# Java 8 Distinct by property

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, distinct-values

In Java 8 how can I filter a collection using the `Stream` API by checking the distinctness of a property of each object?

For example I have a list of `Person` object and I want to remove people with the same name,

```
persons.stream().distinct();
```

Will use the default equality check for a `Person` object, so I need something like,

```
persons.stream().distinct(p -> p.getName());
```

Unfortunately the `distinct()` method has no such overload. Without modifying the equality check inside the `Person` class is it possible to do this succinctly?

Answer (score 922, accepted):

Consider `distinct` to be a *stateful filter*. Here is a function that returns a predicate that maintains state about what it's seen previously, and that returns whether the given element was seen for the first time:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
}
```

Then you can write:

```
persons.stream().filter(distinctByKey(Person::getName))
```

Note that if the stream is ordered and is run in parallel, this will preserve an *arbitrary* element from among the duplicates, instead of the first one, as `distinct()` does.

(This is essentially the same as [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872086/1441122) to this question: [Java Lambda Stream Distinct() on arbitrary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870136/java-lambda-stream-distinct-on-arbitrary-key))

Comment: I guess for better compatibility the argument should be `Function<? super T, ?>`, not `Function<? super T, Object>`. Also it should be noted that for ordered parallel stream this solution does not guarantee which object will be extracted (unlike normal `distinct()`). Also for sequential streams there's additional overhead on using CHM (which is absent in @nosid solution). Finally this solution violates the contract of `filter` method which predicate must be stateless as stated in JavaDoc. Nevertheless upvoted.

Comment: @Stuart, whi are you using concurrentHashMap here?

Comment: @java_newbie The Predicate instance returned by `distinctByKey` has no idea of whether it's being used within a parallel stream. It uses CHM in case it is being used in parallel, though this adds overhead in the sequential case as Tagir Valeev noted above.

Comment: @TagirValeev what are the ramifications of violating the contract of filter here?

Comment: @IcedDante, it works with current implementation of Stream API, but violating contract in general is a bad thing. Another Stream API implementation might use your predicate in another way and may break if you violate the contract.

Comment: Wouldn't this fail on the second run ?

Comment: @holandaGo It will fail if you save and reuse the Predicate instance returned by `distinctByKey`. But it works if you call `distinctByKey` each time, so that it creates a fresh Predicate instance each time.

Comment: You don't need Map for this, Set is sufficient. Collection#add method returns  boolean indicating whether collection was modified by this call. I. e. someSet.add("abc") == true means that "abc" was not seen before.

Comment: Shouldn't the map inside distinctByKey be static?

Comment: @Chinmay no, it shouldn't. If you use `.filter(distinctByKey(...))`. It will execute the method once and return the predicate. So basically the map is already being re-used if you use it properly within a stream. If you would make the map static, the map would be shared for all usages. So if you have two streams using this `distinctByKey()`, both would use the same map, which isn't what you want.

Comment: This is sooo smart and completely non-obvious. *Generally* this is a stateful lambda and the underlying `CallSite` will be linked to the `get$Lambda` method - that will return a new instance of the `Predicate` all the time, but those instances will share the same `map` and `function` as far as I understand. Very nice!

Comment: @StuartMarks, I agree with the last comment, but from a different perspective. I definitely appreciate the elegance of the solution but since it is very non obviouse - I dont think it should be used. In other words - it is simple but not streightforward. And in other-other words: if I see this in code I'm gonna go all "WTF just happened here..." :-)

C#'s IEnumerable does have a Distinct that takes a function and it is very intuitive. I think you should consider just adding this to the API.

Comment: @Vitaliy Well this answer is mainly demonstrating a technique that can be implemented using only Java 8 and Java 9 APIs. Certainly a distinct-by-key operation would be useful to add to the Streams API, but if it is, it won't be available until a future release.

Comment: Worth noting that this will may destroy the encounter order for parallel streams.

Comment: @TagirValeev Finally added a note regarding the choice of duplicate element selected.

Comment: Can I use a `new HashSet()` instead of `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` if  I don't use the `parallel` method of the stream ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé It *might* work, but if it ever accidentally gets put into a parallel stream, it'll almost certainly fail. Sticking with ConcurrentHashMap is probably the safest thing to do.

Comment: It seems use `Set` will break the sequence of the input list.

Comment: @Ninja yes, but this is already mentioned in the answer: "Note that if the stream is ordered and is run in parallel, this will preserve an arbitrary element from among the duplicates, instead of the first one, as distinct() does."

Comment: @AnyulRivas in the first section code, the `keyExtractor.apply(t)` can be replaced with `person.getName()`.Then the code should be easy to read.

Comment: Can somone please explain how a new set is created each time and yet it holds previous values?

Comment: @StuartMarks Awesome answer! I implemented this is a private non-static method in my class and it SEEMS to work fine. Is there anything I might be missing as to why it is static?

Comment: @Pr0pagate It's static because it doesn't depend on anything from the class in which it's declared. As such it can be in a utility class or something. I don't think it's a problem for it to be a non-static method, but it does seem a bit odd in that calls to `foo.distinctByKey()` and `bar.distinctByKey()` don't have anything to do with the `foo` or `bar` instances.

Comment: @javaAndBeyond : `persons.stream().filter(distinctByKey(Person::getName))` is called only once. So does `distinctByKey(Person::getName)`. And so does `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`. The key concept here is that `distinctByKey` return a lambda as a Predicate, and that lambda *capture* the reference stored in `seen` variable *before* been returned. This way the lambad instance access its own underlying Map captured instance. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html for further details about the way this capture macanism behave according to your JRE version.

Comment: for property is null, prefer to add null check
`return t -> null == keyExtractor.apply(t) || seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));`

Comment: As mentioned higher in the comments thread, this solution violates the contract of [`Stream.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)), as the filter predicate is required to be stateless.  `Stream.filter` would be well within its rights to run the same filter against the same stream element twice and use the second predicate result, in which case this would result in an invalid output.  Current stream implementations don't do that, but they could without violating the stream contract.

Answer (score 220):

An alternative would be to place the persons in a map using the name as a key:

```java
persons.collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, p -> p, (p, q) -> p)).values();
```

Note that the `Person` that is kept, in the case of a duplicate name, will be the first encountered.

Comment: This does create memory overhead though, which may not be what you want.

Comment: @skiwi: do you think there is a way to implement `distinct()` without that overhead? How would any implementation know if it has seen an object before without actually remembering all distinct values it has seen? So the overhead of `toMap` and `distinct` is very likely the same.

Comment: @Holger I may have been wrong there as I hadn't thought abou the overhead `distinct()` itself creates.

Comment: And obviously it messes up the original order of the list

Comment: 'Stream#collect' is terminal operation. There may be need in further processing after deduplicating - sorting, concatenation, mapping/flatMapping, etc. Though there are Collectors for some of those ops.

Comment: @Philipp: could be fixed by changing to `persons.collect(toMap(Person::getName, p -> p, (p, q) -> p, LinkedHashMap::new)).values();`

Comment: @Holger if the input stream is sorted, then all the identical items are next to each other, hence it is only necessary to remember the previous item to see if the next one is the same as it and can be skipped. Streams internally have a way of indicating that they are sorted.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker this question is about "distinct by property". It would require the stream to be sorted *by the same property*, to be able to take advantage of it. First, the OP did never state that the stream is sorted at all. Second, streams are not able to detect whether they are sorted *by a certain property*. Third, there is no genuine "distinct by property" stream operation to do what you suggest. Forth, in practice, there are only two ways to get such a sorted stream. A sorted source (`TreeSet`) which is already distinct anyway or `sorted` on the stream which also buffers all elements.

Comment: @Holger was answering your comment, not the question.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker and my comment was made in the context of this question.

Comment: Replay the sample online  with https://repl.it/@SmaMa/DistinctListByProperty

Comment: I personally like to use the identify function for readability changing to: `persons.collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Function.identity(), (p, q) -> p)).values();`

Comment: "Note that the `Person` that is kept, in the case of a duplicate name, will be the first encountered." — This is not actually guaranteed by the Stream specification, though current implementations of streams probably do have this characteristic (even if they don't guarantee it).

Answer (score 141):

You can wrap the person objects into another class, that only compares the names of the persons. Afterward, you unwrap the wrapped objects to get a person stream again. The stream operations might look as follows:

```
persons.stream()
    .map(Wrapper::new)
    .distinct()
    .map(Wrapper::unwrap)
    ...;
```

The class `Wrapper` might look as follows:

```
class Wrapper {
    private final Person person;
    public Wrapper(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
    public Person unwrap() {
        return person;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Wrapper) {
            return ((Wrapper) other).person.getName().equals(person.getName());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return person.getName().hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is called the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Comment: @StuartCaie Not really... there's no memoization, and the point is not performance, but adaptation to the existing API.

Comment: com.google.common.base.Equivalence.wrap(S) and com.google.common.base.Equivalence.Wrapper.get() could help too.

Comment: You could make the wrapper class generic and parametrized by a key extraction function.

Comment: The `equals` method can be simplified to `return other instanceof Wrapper && ((Wrapper) other).person.getName().equals(person.getName());`

Comment: I really prefer this solution, because it lets you test more than just one attribute. +1 to Guava ```Equivalence``` class, looks like it was built for exactly this.

Comment: To expand on @bjmi's suggestion, here's an example usage: `persons.stream().map(Equivalence.equals().onResultOf(Person::getName)::wrap).distinct().map(Equivalence.Wrapper::get)....`

Answer (score 95):

Another solution, using `Set`. May not be the ideal solution, but it works

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(persons.size());
persons.stream().filter(p -> set.add(p.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or if you can modify the original list, you can use [removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method

```
persons.removeIf(p -> !set.add(p.getName()));
```

Comment: This is the best answer if you are not using any third party libraries!

Comment: using genious idea that Set.add returns true if this set did not already contain the specified element. +1

Comment: I believe this method does not work for parallel stream processing, as it it is not thread-safe.

Comment: @LoBo Probably not. This is just an idea, which will work for simple cases. Users can extend it for thread safety/parallelism.

Comment: Interesting approach, but looks kind of like an anti-pattern to modify an external collection (set) whilst filtering a stream on another collection (persons)...

Comment: @JustinRowe, you can create the external `Set` in a function so that it is not used for anything else. To make it thread-safe one can use `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` to create the `Set`, and then this answer becomes identical to the accepted answer from Stuart Marks.

Comment: @JustinRowe This is definitely an antipattern.  [`Stream.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) requires the filter predicate to be stateless, which this very much is not.

Answer (score 37):

There's a simpler approach using a TreeSet with a custom comparator.

```
persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(
      () -> new TreeSet<Person>((p1, p2) -> p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName())) 
));
```

Comment: I think your answer helps towards the ordering and not towards uniqueness. However it helped me set my thoughts on how to do it. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019854/java-distinct-list-of-objects/1019870#1019870

Comment: Keep in mind you will be paying the price for sorting the elements here and we do not need sorting in order to find duplicates or even remove duplicates.

Comment: Comparator.comparing(Person::getName)

Answer (score 28):

We can also use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) (very powerful [reactive extension](http://reactivex.io/) library)

```
Observable.from(persons).distinct(Person::getName)
```

or

```
Observable.from(persons).distinct(p -> p.getName())
```

Comment: Rx is awesome, but this is a poor answer. `Observable` is push-based whereas `Stream` is pull-based. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216979/difference-between-java-8-streams-and-rxjava-observables

Comment: the question ask for a java8 solution not necessarily using stream. My answer show that java8 stream api is less powefull than rx api

Comment: Using [reactor](https://projectreactor.io/), it will be `Flux.fromIterable(persons).distinct(p -> p.getName())`

Comment: The question literally says "using the `Stream` API", not "not necessarily using stream".  That said, this is a great solution to the XY problem of filtering the stream to distinct values.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `groupingBy` collector:

```java
persons.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getName()))
        .values()
        .forEach(t -> System.out.println(t.get(0).getId()));
```

If you want to have another stream you can use this:

```java
persons.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getName()))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .map(l -> l.get(0));
```

Answer (score 15):

Similar approach which Saeed Zarinfam used but more Java 8 style:)

```
persons.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getName())).values().stream()
 .map(plans -> plans.stream().findFirst().get())
 .collect(toList());
```

Comment: I'd replace map line with `flatMap(plans -> plans.stream().findFirst().stream())` it avoids use of  get on Optional

Comment: Maybe this is also ok:
flatMap(plans -> plans.stream().limit(1))

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `distinct(HashingStrategy)` method in [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
List<Person> persons = ...;
MutableList<Person> distinct =
    ListIterate.distinct(persons, HashingStrategies.fromFunction(Person::getName));
```

If you can refactor `persons` to implement an Eclipse Collections interface, you can call the method directly on the list.

```
MutableList<Person> persons = ...;
MutableList<Person> distinct =
    persons.distinct(HashingStrategies.fromFunction(Person::getName));
```

[HashingStrategy](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/eclipse-collections-api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/collections/api/block/HashingStrategy.java) is simply a strategy interface that allows you to define custom implementations of equals and hashcode.

```
public interface HashingStrategy<E>
{
    int computeHashCode(E object);
    boolean equals(E object1, E object2);
}
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Comment: The method distinctBy was added in Eclipse Collections 9.0 which can further simplify this solution.  https://medium.com/@donraab/nine-features-in-eclipse-collections-9-0-a2ca97dfdf74

Answer (score 14):

My approach to this is to group all the objects with same property together, then cut short the groups to size of 1 and then finally collect them as a `List`.

```
  List<YourPersonClass> listWithDistinctPersons =   persons.stream()
            //operators to remove duplicates based on person name
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getName()))
            .values()
            .stream()
            //cut short the groups to size of 1
            .flatMap(group -> group.stream().limit(1))
            //collect distinct users as list
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 12):

I recommend using [Vavr](http://www.vavr.io/), if you can. With this library you can do the following:

```
io.vavr.collection.List.ofAll(persons)
                       .distinctBy(Person::getName)
                       .toJavaSet() // or any another Java 8 Collection
```

Comment: Formerly known as "javaslang" library.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library:

```
StreamEx.of(persons)
        .distinct(Person::getName)
        .toList()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that method of the otherwise awesome StreamEx library is poorly designed - it compares object equality instead of using equals. This may work for `String`s thanks to string interning, but it also may not.

Comment: @Torque that is not the case (anymore?), StreamEx uses `Objects#equals` on the extracted values

Answer (score 11):

Distinct objects list can be found using:

```
 List distinctPersons = persons.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Person:: getName))),
                            ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 10):

Extending Stuart Marks's answer, this can be done in a shorter way and without a concurrent map (if you don't need parallel streams):

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    final Set<Object> seen = new HashSet<>();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
}
```

Then call:

```
persons.stream().filter(distinctByKey(p -> p.getName());
```

Comment: This one doesn't take into consideration that the stream might be parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've updated my answer. If you don't need a parallel stream, not using concurrent maps gives you much better performance.

Comment: Your code would probably work for parallel collections if you created a `Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>())` instead. But it would probably be slower than with a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Answer (score 8):

I made a generic version:

```
private <T, R> Collector<T, ?, Stream<T>> distinctByKey(Function<T, R> keyExtractor) {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            toMap(
                    keyExtractor,
                    t -> t,
                    (t1, t2) -> t1
            ),
            (Map<R, T> map) -> map.values().stream()
    );
}
```

An exemple:

```
Stream.of(new Person("Jean"), 
          new Person("Jean"),
          new Person("Paul")
)
    .filter(...)
    .collect(distinctByKey(Person::getName)) // return a stream of Person with 2 elements, jean and Paul
    .map(...)
    .collect(toList())
```

Answer (score 8):

Another library that supports this is [jOOλ](https://github.com/jooq/jool), and its [`Seq.distinct(Function<T,U>)`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.14/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html#distinct-java.util.function.Function-) method:

```
Seq.seq(persons).distinct(Person::getName).toList();
```

[Under the hood](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL/blob/master/jOOL/src/main/java/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.java), it does practically the same thing as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/2032415), though.

Answer (score 8):

While the highest upvoted answer is absolutely best answer wrt Java 8, it is at the same time absolutely worst in terms of performance. If you really want a bad low performant application, then go ahead and use it. Simple requirement of extracting a unique set of Person Names shall be achieved by mere "For-Each" and a "Set".
Things get even worse if list is above size of 10.

Consider you have a collection of 20 Objects, like this:

```
public static final List<SimpleEvent> testList = Arrays.asList(
            new SimpleEvent("Tom"), new SimpleEvent("Dick"),new SimpleEvent("Harry"),new SimpleEvent("Tom"),
            new SimpleEvent("Dick"),new SimpleEvent("Huckle"),new SimpleEvent("Berry"),new SimpleEvent("Tom"),
            new SimpleEvent("Dick"),new SimpleEvent("Moses"),new SimpleEvent("Chiku"),new SimpleEvent("Cherry"),
            new SimpleEvent("Roses"),new SimpleEvent("Moses"),new SimpleEvent("Chiku"),new SimpleEvent("gotya"),
            new SimpleEvent("Gotye"),new SimpleEvent("Nibble"),new SimpleEvent("Berry"),new SimpleEvent("Jibble"));
```

Where you object `SimpleEvent` looks like this:

```
public class SimpleEvent {

private String name;
private String type;

public SimpleEvent(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = "type_"+name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
}
```

And to test, you have **[JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)** code like this,(Please note, im using the same **distinctByKey** Predicate mentioned in accepted answer) :

```
@Benchmark
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public void aStreamBasedUniqueSet(Blackhole blackhole) throws Exception{

    Set<String> uniqueNames = testList
            .stream()
            .filter(distinctByKey(SimpleEvent::getName))
            .map(SimpleEvent::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    blackhole.consume(uniqueNames);
}

@Benchmark
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public void aForEachBasedUniqueSet(Blackhole blackhole) throws Exception{
    Set<String> uniqueNames = new HashSet<>();

    for (SimpleEvent event : testList) {
        uniqueNames.add(event.getName());
    }
    blackhole.consume(uniqueNames);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(MyBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
            .forks(1)
            .mode(Mode.Throughput)
            .warmupBatchSize(3)
            .warmupIterations(3)
            .measurementIterations(3)
            .build();

    new Runner(opt).run();
}
```

Then you'll have **Benchmark** results like this:

```
Benchmark                                  Mode  Samples        Score  Score error  Units
c.s.MyBenchmark.aForEachBasedUniqueSet    thrpt        3  2635199.952  1663320.718  ops/s
c.s.MyBenchmark.aStreamBasedUniqueSet     thrpt        3   729134.695   895825.697  ops/s
```

And as you can see, a simple **For-Each** is 3 times better in throughput and less in error score as compared to Java 8 Stream.

***Higher*** the throughput, **better** the performance

Comment: Thanks, but the question was very specifically in the context of the Stream API

Comment: Yes, i agree, i've already mentioned "While the highest upvoted answer is absolutely best answer wrt Java 8" . A problem can be solve in n different ways, and im trying to highlight here that the issue in hand can be solved simply, rather than dangerously with Java 8 Streams , where the danger being performance degradation. :)

Answer (score 8):

I would like to improve Stuart Marks [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/1321893). What if the key is null, it will through `NullPointerException`.  Here I ignore the null key by adding one more check as  `keyExtractor.apply(t)!=null`.

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
return t -> keyExtractor.apply(t)!=null && seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
```

}

Comment: I'd cache the result of `apply` in a local variable, then do `return key != null && seen.add(key)`. This is just in case `keyExtractor` is somehow expensive.

Answer (score 7):

```
Set<YourPropertyType> set = new HashSet<>();
list
        .stream()
        .filter(it -> set.add(it.getYourProperty()))
        .forEach(it -> ...);
```

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: For those who might confuse for "...", replace with "it.getYourProperty()"

Answer (score 7):

This works like a charm:

1. Grouping the data by unique key to form a map.
2. Returning the first object from every value of the map (There could be multiple person having same name).

```
persons.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Person::getName))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(values -> values.stream().limit(1))
    .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

There are lot of approaches, this one will also help - Simple, Clean and Clear

```
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    employees.add(new Employee(11, "Ravi"));
    employees.add(new Employee(12, "Stalin"));
    employees.add(new Employee(23, "Anbu"));
    employees.add(new Employee(24, "Yuvaraj"));
    employees.add(new Employee(35, "Sena"));
    employees.add(new Employee(36, "Antony"));
    employees.add(new Employee(47, "Sena"));
    employees.add(new Employee(48, "Ravi"));

    List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>(employees.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(Employee::getName, obj -> obj,
                    (existingValue, newValue) -> existingValue))
                   .values());

    empList.forEach(System.out::println);


    //  Collectors.toMap(
    //  Employee::getName, - key (the value by which you want to eliminate duplicate)
    //  obj -> obj,  - value (entire employee object)
    //  (existingValue, newValue) -> existingValue) - to avoid illegalstateexception: duplicate key
```

**Output - toString() overloaded**

```
Employee{id=35, name='Sena'}
Employee{id=12, name='Stalin'}
Employee{id=11, name='Ravi'}
Employee{id=24, name='Yuvaraj'}
Employee{id=36, name='Antony'}
Employee{id=23, name='Anbu'}
```

Comment: Like your approach , and good explanation !

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to implement this is to jump on the sort feature as it already provides an optional `Comparator` which can be created using an element’s property. Then you have to filter duplicates out which can be done using a statefull `Predicate` which uses the fact that for a sorted stream all equal elements are adjacent:

```
Comparator<Person> c=Comparator.comparing(Person::getName);
stream.sorted(c).filter(new Predicate<Person>() {
    Person previous;
    public boolean test(Person p) {
      if(previous!=null && c.compare(previous, p)==0)
        return false;
      previous=p;
      return true;
    }
})./* more stream operations here */;
```

Of course, a statefull `Predicate` is not thread-safe, however if that’s your need you can move this logic into a `Collector` and let the stream take care of the thread-safety when using your `Collector`. This depends on what you want to do with the stream of distinct elements which you didn’t tell us in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example:

```java
public class PayRoll {
    
    private int payRollId;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String dept;
    private int salary;
    
    
    public PayRoll(int payRollId, int id, String name, String dept, int salary) {
        super();
        this.payRollId = payRollId;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.dept = dept;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Prac {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int salary=70000;
        PayRoll payRoll=new PayRoll(1311, 1, "A", "HR", salary);
        PayRoll payRoll2=new PayRoll(1411, 2    , "B", "Technical", salary);
        PayRoll payRoll3=new PayRoll(1511, 1, "C", "HR", salary);
        PayRoll payRoll4=new PayRoll(1611, 1, "D", "Technical", salary);
        PayRoll payRoll5=new PayRoll(711, 3,"E", "Technical", salary);
        PayRoll payRoll6=new PayRoll(1811, 3, "F", "Technical", salary);
        List<PayRoll>list=new ArrayList<PayRoll>();
        list.add(payRoll);
        list.add(payRoll2);
        list.add(payRoll3);
        list.add(payRoll4);
        list.add(payRoll5);
        list.add(payRoll6);


        Map<Object, Optional<PayRoll>> k = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.getId()+"|"+p.getDept(),Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(PayRoll::getPayRollId))));


        k.entrySet().forEach(p->
        {
            if(p.getValue().isPresent())
            {
                System.out.println(p.getValue().get());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Output:

```
PayRoll [payRollId=1611, id=1, name=D, dept=Technical, salary=70000]
PayRoll [payRollId=1811, id=3, name=F, dept=Technical, salary=70000]
PayRoll [payRollId=1411, id=2, name=B, dept=Technical, salary=70000]
PayRoll [payRollId=1511, id=1, name=C, dept=HR, salary=70000]
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @josketres's answer, I created a generic utility method:

You could make this more Java 8-friendly by creating a [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html).

```
public static <T> Set<T> removeDuplicates(Collection<T> input, Comparator<T> comparer) {
    return input.stream()
            .collect(toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(comparer)));
}


@Test
public void removeDuplicatesWithDuplicates() {
    ArrayList<C> input = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(input, new C(7), new C(42), new C(42));
    Collection<C> result = removeDuplicates(input, (c1, c2) -> Integer.compare(c1.value, c2.value));
    assertEquals(2, result.size());
    assertTrue(result.stream().anyMatch(c -> c.value == 7));
    assertTrue(result.stream().anyMatch(c -> c.value == 42));
}

@Test
public void removeDuplicatesWithoutDuplicates() {
    ArrayList<C> input = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(input, new C(1), new C(2), new C(3));
    Collection<C> result = removeDuplicates(input, (t1, t2) -> Integer.compare(t1.value, t2.value));
    assertEquals(3, result.size());
    assertTrue(result.stream().anyMatch(c -> c.value == 1));
    assertTrue(result.stream().anyMatch(c -> c.value == 2));
    assertTrue(result.stream().anyMatch(c -> c.value == 3));
}

private class C {
    public final int value;

    private C(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe will be useful for somebody. I had a little bit another requirement. Having list of objects `A` from 3rd party remove all which have same `A.b` field for same `A.id` (multiple `A` object with same `A.id` in  list). [Stream partition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32435407/4899609) answer by [Tagir Valeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856258/tagir-valeev) inspired me to use custom `Collector` which returns `Map<A.id, List<A>>`. Simple `flatMap` will do the rest.

```
 public static <T, K, K2> Collector<T, ?, Map<K, List<T>>> groupingDistinctBy(Function<T, K> keyFunction, Function<T, K2> distinctFunction) {
    return groupingBy(keyFunction, Collector.of((Supplier<Map<K2, T>>) HashMap::new,
            (map, error) -> map.putIfAbsent(distinctFunction.apply(error), error),
            (left, right) -> {
                left.putAll(right);
                return left;
            }, map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values()),
            Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED)); }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation, where I was suppose to get distinct elements from list based on 2 keys.
If you want distinct based on two keys or may composite key, try this:

```
class Person{
    int rollno;
    String name;
}
List<Person> personList;


Function<Person, List<Object>> compositeKey = personList->
        Arrays.<Object>asList(personList.getName(), personList.getRollno());

Map<Object, List<Person>> map = personList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(compositeKey, Collectors.toList()));

List<Object> duplicateEntrys = map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(settingMap ->
                settingMap.getValue().size() > 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I sometimes use this one-liner as an equivalent:

```
((Function<Value, Key>) Value::getKey).andThen(new HashSet<>()::add)::apply
```

The expression is a `Predicate<Value>` but since the map is inline, it works as a filter. This is of course less readable but sometimes it can be helpful to avoid the method.

Comment: looks impressive - but how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

The [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature adds support for gatherer operations, which could be used to filter the stream for distinct elements according to some function:

```java
void main() {
    List<Person> persons = List.of(
            new Person("A"), new Person("B"), new Person("C"), new Person("A"),
            new Person("D"), new Person("B")
    );

    List<Person> distinct = 
            persons.stream().gather(distinctBy(Person::getName)).toList();

    // [Person[name=A], Person[name=B], Person[name=C], Person[name=D]]
    System.out.println(distinct);
}

static <T, R> Gatherer<T, ?, T> distinctBy(Function<T, R> function) {
    Gatherer.Integrator.Greedy<Set<R>, T, T> integrator =
            (state, element, downstream) -> {
                R functionResult = function.apply(element);
                if (state.contains(functionResult)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    state.add(functionResult);
                    return downstream.push(element);
                }
            };
    return Gatherer.ofSequential(
            HashSet::new,
            Gatherer.Integrator.ofGreedy(integrator)
    );
}
```

The custom gatherer keeps track of the whether a given value has been encountered before based on the result of applying a function to each stream element.  If a given function value has not been encountered yet, the stream element is pushed downstream.

Granted, this is a fair amount of code in isolation, but it is a reusable intermediate operation for any stream that needs to operate only on distinct elements based on a given function.

Here is the same solution, with a one-off gatherer specific to the `Person` scenario:

```java
List<Person> distinct = persons.stream().gather(Gatherer.ofSequential(
        HashSet::new,
        Gatherer.Integrator.<Set<String>, Person, Person>ofGreedy(
                (state, element, downstream) -> {
                    String name = element.getName();
                    if (state.contains(name)) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        state.add(name);
                        return downstream.push(element);
                    }
                })
)).toList();
```

## Javadocs

[`Gatherer`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.
>
> **API Note:**
>
> A `Gatherer` is specified by four functions that work together to process input elements, optionally using intermediate state, and optionally perform a final action at the end of input. They are:
>
> - creating a new, potentially mutable, state ([`initializer()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#initializer()))
> - integrating a new input element ([`integrator()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#integrator()))
> - combining two states into one ([`combiner()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#combiner()))
> - performing an optional final action ([`finisher()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#finisher()))

[`Stream.gather(Gatherer<? super T,?,R> gatherer)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherer.ofSequential(initializer, integrator)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#ofSequential(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Gatherer.Integrator))

> Returns a new, sequential, `Gatherer` described by the given `initializer` and `integrator`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in this listing:

```
List<HolderEntry> result ....

List<HolderEntry> dto3s = new ArrayList<>(result.stream().collect(toMap(
            HolderEntry::getId,
            holder -> holder,  //or Function.identity() if you want
            (holder1, holder2) -> holder1 
    )).values());
```

In my situation i want to find distinct values and put their in List.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/234593) that handles `null`:

```java
    public static <T, K> Predicate<T> distinctBy(final Function<? super T, K> getKey) {
        val seen = ConcurrentHashMap.<Optional<K>>newKeySet();
        return obj -> seen.add(Optional.ofNullable(getKey.apply(obj)));
    }
```

In my tests:

```java
        assertEquals(
                asList("a", "bb"),
                Stream.of("a", "b", "bb", "aa").filter(distinctBy(String::length)).collect(toList()));

        assertEquals(
                asList(5, null, 2, 3),
                Stream.of(5, null, 2, null, 3, 3, 2).filter(distinctBy(x -> x)).collect(toList()));

        val maps = asList(
                hashMapWith(0, 2),
                hashMapWith(1, 2),
                hashMapWith(2, null),
                hashMapWith(3, 1),
                hashMapWith(4, null),
                hashMapWith(5, 2));

        assertEquals(
                asList(0, 2, 3),
                maps.stream()
                        .filter(distinctBy(m -> m.get("val")))
                        .map(m -> m.get("i"))
                        .collect(toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone is sharing their own ideas and implementation I also have one, it's not an efficient one, but it's working:

```
Set<String> personNameList = personList.stream().
map(tempPerson->tempPerson.getName()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

personList.stream().
                   collect(()->new ArrayList<Person>(),
                           (l1,p)->{
                                  if(!personNameList.contains(p.getName())) {
                                        l1.add(p);
                                  }
        }, ArrayList::addAll);
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I needed to control what was the previous element. I then created a **stateful** Predicate where I controled if the previous element was  different from the current element, in that case I kept it.

```
public List<Log> fetchLogById(Long id) {
    return this.findLogById(id).stream()
        .filter(new LogPredicate())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public class LogPredicate implements Predicate<Log> {

    private Log previous;

    public boolean test(Log atual) {
        boolean isDifferent = previouws == null || verifyIfDifferentLog(current, previous);

        if (isDifferent) {
            previous = current;
        }
        return isDifferent;
    }

    private boolean verifyIfDifferentLog(Log current, Log previous) {
        return !current.getId().equals(previous.getId());
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to List of Persons following would be the simple way

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(persons.size());
persons.stream().filter(p -> set.add(p.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Additionally, if you want to find distinct or unique **list of names**, **not Person** , you can do using following two method as well.

Method 1: using `distinct`

```
persons.stream().map(x->x.getName()).distinct.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Method 2: using `HashSet`

```
Set<E> set = new HashSet<>();
set.addAll(person.stream().map(x->x.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: This produces a list of names, not `Person`s.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I needed a single line method to eliminate duplicates while transforming a collection to one other. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

What's about this solution.

It will only work if your key implements Equal which most base types do, but it's a little bit simpler.

`person.stream().map(person -> p.getName()).distinct()`

Comment: Won't this answer return an array with only the person names? I think he wants to still keep the array with the full objects, just removing ones that have the same name (kinda the same problem i'm having)

Comment: I knew, but I think it will be helpfull for others getting here

Comment: thank you, this was exactly, what I was looking for in my case!

Answer (score -4):

The Most simple code you can write:

```
    persons.stream().map(x-> x.getName()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That'll get a distinct list of names though, not Persons by name