# How do filter out this list with java 8 streams and functional interfaces?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8

if I have a list of arrays like this (pseudo java code):

Note the list valsSorted will be always sorted with x[0] asc and x[1] desc order.

```
List valsSorted = {[1 5][1 4][1 3][2 1][3 2][3 1][4 2][4 1][5 1][6 2][6 1]};
```

How do I filter this list with Java 8 streams and lambdas so that I get:

```
result  = {[1 5][2 1][3 2][4 2][5 1][6 2]}
```

The first item of the array (x[0]) is ID and the second is a version number. So the rule is give all distinct IDs with the highest version back.

If I would use a for loop the following code would be fine:

```
 ArrayList<int[]> result= new ArrayList();
    int keep = -1;
    for (int[] x : valsSorted) {
        int id = x[0];
        int version = x[1];
        if(keep == id)   continue;
        keep = id;
        result.add(x);
    }
```

Comment: What's supposed to be the rule here?

Comment: the first item of the array (x[0]) is ID and the second is a version number. so the rule is give all distinct  IDs with the highest version back?

Comment: I see. Well, that would be difficult in one step, I'd first group them into a list of lists (based on id) and then pick the biggest version number from each list in the second step.

Comment: yep you may be right. But I was hopping to somehow avoid creating immediate collections. I actually have some other filters to run after so I would like to not realise the stream

Comment: Picking out the biggest element of a collection requires some sort of state because the choice depends on all the elements, not just the one being examined.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of the word "distinct" suggests using the `distinct()` stream operation. Unfortunately that operation is hardwired to use the `equals()` method of the stream elements, which isn't useful for arrays. One approach for dealing with this would be to wrap the arrays in a wrapper object that has the semantics of equality that you're looking for:

```
class Wrapper {
    final int[] array;

    Wrapper(int[] array) { this.array = array; }

    int[] getArray() { return array; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (! (other instanceof Wrapper))
            return false;
        else
            return this.array[0] == ((Wrapper)other).array[0];
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { ... }
}
```

Then wrap up your object before `distinct()` and unwrap it after:

```
List<int[]> valsDistinct =
    valsSorted.stream()
        .map(Wrapper::new)
        .distinct()
        .map(Wrapper::getArray)
        .collect(toList());
```

This makes one pass over the data but it generates a garbage object per value. This also relies on the stream elements being processed in-order since you want the first one.

Another approach would be to use some kind of stateful collector, but that will end up storing the entire result list before any subsequent processing begins, which you said you wanted to avoid.

It might be worth considering making the data elements be actual classes instead of two-element arrays. This way you can provide a reasonable notion of equality, and you can also make the values comparable so that you can sort them easily.

(Credit: technique stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23699499/1441122).)

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I also like the version of the state full Predicate in the link you provided

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test{
     List<Point> valsSorted = Arrays.asList(new Point(1,5),
          new Point(1,4),
          new Point(1,3),
          new Point(2,1),
          new Point(3,2),
          new Point(3,1),
          new Point(4,2),
          new Point(4,1),
          new Point(5,1),
          new Point(6,2),
          new Point(6,1));

     public Test(){
        List<Point> c = valsSorted.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Point::getX))
              .values()
              .stream()
              .map(j -> j.get(0))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for(int i=0; i < c.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(c.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        Test t = new Test()
    }
}
```

I decided to use the point class and represent the ID field as x and the version number as Y. So from there if you create a stream and group them by ID. You can call the values method which returns a Collection of Lists `Collection<List<Point>>`. You can then call the stream for this Collection and get the first value from each list which according to your specifications is ordered with descending version number so it should be the the highest version number. From there all you have to do is collect them into a list, array or whatever you see necessary and assign it as needed.

The only problem here is that they are printed out of order. That should be an easy fix though.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it creates an intermediate collection so it must 2 times use stream() . But maybe I will go with your solution because it shows most clearly the intent and also can be executed concurrently because it does not depend on state