# Java8 Streams - Remove Duplicates With Stream Distinct

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream such as:

```
Arrays.stream(new String[]{"matt", "jason", "michael"});
```

I would like to remove names that begin with the same letter so that only one name (doesn't matter which) beginning with that letter is left.

I'm trying to understand how the [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) method works.  I read in the documentation that it's based on the "equals" method of an object.  However, when I try wrapping the String, I notice that the equals method is never called and nothing is removed.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Wrapper Class:

```
static class Wrp {
    String test;
    Wrp(String s){
        this.test = s;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        return this.test.charAt(0) == ((Wrp) other).test.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

And some simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Arrays.stream(new String[]{"matt", "jason", "michael"})
    .map(Wrp::new)
    .distinct()
    .map(wrp -> wrp.test)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: There's the technique I described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27872086/1441122). (Scroll to the end of the answer). This would let you do `filter(distinctByKey(s -> s.charAt(0)))`.

Comment: Side note: for a stream of literals, it's often easier to use `Stream.of("matt", "jason", "michael")`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Whenever you override `equals`, you also need to override the `hashCode()` method, which will be used in the implementation of `distinct()`.

In this case, you could just use

```
@Override public int hashCode() {
   return test.charAt(0);
}
```

...which would work just fine.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to work.  It would be nice if you could pass a comparator into `distinct` to make this a bit easier.

Comment: If that's what you want, you can just dump it into a `TreeSet`.

Comment: You are correct...  Sometimes when you get a new hammer everything starts to look like a nail.  ;-)

Answer (score 25):

Alternative approach

```
    String[] array = {"matt", "jason", "michael"};
    Arrays.stream(array)
            .map(name-> name.charAt(0))
            .distinct()
            .map(ch -> Arrays.stream(array).filter(name->name.charAt(0) == ch).findAny().get())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using Stream.filter and HashSet.add:

```
Set<Character> distinct = new HashSet<>();
Arrays.stream(new String[]{"matt", "jason", "michael"})
    .filter(m -> distinct.add(m.charAt(0)))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

will print

```
matt
jason
```

The method HashSet.add is returning false if you try to add some object that already exists in it.