# Checking the value of current object value against others

Tags: java

I am trying to remove all duplicate objects with the same value in one property.I have `courses[]` objects and they all contain a `courseLevel` that is composed of one four digit `integer`.

I am incrementing `x` from `0` in a loop and storing the data and reseting it every iteration of the loop to store new information in the next incremented `courses[x]` object.

```
        for (int n = 0; n < courses.length; n++) {
            if (courses[x].getCourseLevel() == courses[n].getCourseLevel()) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate" + courses[x]);
            }  
         }
```

As you can see I start with `courses[x]` and want to check if its `courseLevel` is equal to any of the other objects that have been created to that point but the problem is it checks its self,How can I check all `courses[n]` except `courses[x]`

Tried using equals() but couldn't compare int types.

Comment: You could try `&& x != n`

Comment: The simpler way would be to override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods and then put all the objects in a `Set` to get only the unique objects.

Comment: I actually tried that.I added all my objects to a list.Then to a set and back into the list.I then sorted them by the courseLevel(ascending).I still have dups though.

Comment: If you are using Java 8 then you can use approach from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870136/java-lambda-stream-distinct-on-arbitrary-key). Just transform your array to stream: Arrays.stream(courses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int n = 0; n < courses.length; n++) {
        if ((courses[x].getCourseLevel() == courses[n].getCourseLevel()) && x != n) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate" + courses[x]);
        }  
     }
```