# Java 8 filter list of pojos based on nested object attribute

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of Thingy pojos, such that:

```
public class Thingy {
    private DifferentThingy nestedThingy;
    public DifferentThingy getNestedThingy() {
        return this.nestedThingy;
    }
}
```

...

```
public class DifferentThingy {
    private String attr;
    public String getAttr() {
        return this.attr;
    }
}
```

I want to filter a

```
List<Thingy>
```

to be unique based on the

```
attr
```

of the Thingy's

```
DifferentThingy
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
private List<Thingy> getUniqueBasedOnDifferentThingyAttr(List<Thingy> originalList) {
    List<Thingy> uniqueItems = new ArrayList<Thingy>();
    Set<String> encounteredNestedDiffThingyAttrs= new HashSet<String>();
    for (Thingy t: originalList) {
        String nestedDiffThingyAttr = t.getNestedThingy().getAttr();
        if(!encounteredNestedDiffThingyAttrs.contains(nestedDiffThingyAttr)) {
            encounteredNestedDiffThingyAttrs.add(nestedDiffThingyAttr);
            uniqueItems.add(t);
        }
    }
    return uniqueItems;
}
```

I want to do this using a Java 8 stream and lambdas for the two getters that end up retrieving the attribute used for determining uniqueness, but am unsure how.  I know how to do it when the attribute for comparison is on the top level of the pojo, but not when the attribute is nested in another object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Lambda Stream Distinct() on arbitrary key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870136/java-lambda-stream-distinct-on-arbitrary-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it that way:

```
originalList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(thing -> thing.getNestedThingy().getAttr(), p -> p, (p, q) -> p))
    .values();
```

Not sure if the most optimal way though, I'm on Android, so don't use streams in daily job.

**UPD**

For someone can not compile it, there is [full code](https://gist.github.com/kidinov/39daa2fa0beedc0261730505f3799b0a) of my test file.

Comment: Anyone tested the above? I have got a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Values cannot be cast to java.util.List`.

Comment: My solution is about the same:
  public static Collection<Thingy> getUniqueBasedOnDifferentThingyAttr(List<Thingy> originalList) {
    return originalList.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t.getNestedThingy().getAttr(), t -> t))
      .values();
  }

Comment: @Andreas, I think it depends on which one they want when a collision happens.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz yes, I wrote it in idea, and it's 100% working code

Comment: @JellyRaptor I've added link to full code of my test class.

Comment: This is the fastest of the supplied answers that I could test.  I didn't originally accept it because I couldn't compile it earlier for some reason.  Even with the overhead of having to explicitly convert the Collection to a List, it is a few ms faster than Hank D's answer and about 10 times faster than the originally accepted one.

Comment: @4castle Can you please demonstrate what you are saying about Collectors.groupingBy()?  I haven't been able to use that on top of Diver's answer.

Comment: @JellyRaptor It's actually not much of a shorthand, so nevermind `Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getNestedThingy().getAttr(), Collectors.reducing((a, b) -> a))`

Answer (score 4):

What about making it far more explicit using [javaslang](http://www.javaslang.io/)

```
javaslang.collection.List.ofAll(thingies)
  .distinctBy(t -> t.getNestedThingy().getAttr());
```

> Javaslang core is a functional library for Java 8+. It helps to reduce the amount of code and to increase the robustness. A first step towards functional programming is to start thinking in immutable values. Javaslang provides immutable collections and the necessary functions and control structures to operate on these values. The results are beautiful and just work.

Answer (score 2):

I keep a set of unique nested thingies' attributes...
then I try to add an element to it.
When the set "grows", it means that an unique element has been encountered.
When the set size does not change, it means that this `Thingy` has a `NestedThingy` with an already encountered attribute.
Together with a simple test that would be:

```
public class Thingies {

    public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
        final Set<Object> seen = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
        return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
    }

    private static List<Thingy> getUniqueBasedOnDifferentThingyAttr(List<Thingy> originalList) {
        return originalList.stream()
                .filter(distinctByKey(thingy -> thingy.getNestedThingy().getAttr()))
                .collect(toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Thingy> originalList = new ArrayList<>();
        originalList.add(new Thingy(new DifferentThingy("first")));
        originalList.add(new Thingy(new DifferentThingy("first")));
        originalList.add(new Thingy(new DifferentThingy("second")));
        System.out.println(getUniqueBasedOnDifferentThingyAttr(originalList));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[first, second]
```

The original answer, which helped the OP, (a bit lengthy and not good for parallel streams) contained such a method instead:

```
private static List<Thingy> getUniqueBasedOnDifferentThingyAttr(List<Thingy> originalList) {
    final Set<String> uniqueAttributes = new HashSet<>(originalList.size());
    return originalList.stream()
            .filter(thingy -> {
                int initialSize = uniqueAttributes.size();
                uniqueAttributes.add(thingy.getNestedThingy().getAttr());
                return initialSize != uniqueAttributes.size();
            }).collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: This works if I change toList() to Collectors.toList()

Comment: Then go for it ;) I can try to make it a bit shorter with an `distinctBy` method implementation.

Comment: Change outer value from inside stream chain looks duty for me.

Comment: @Divers, it is contained in one method. Reassigning a variable is a bad practice (here impossible because of `final`), making use of its mutability (here: `add` method call) is a common practice, especially in `void` methods. Having said this, I still like your code... it returns an instance of `Collection<Thingy>` instead of `List<Thingy>`, which is its only drawback (very easy to fix).

Comment: It's a bad practice, because functional programming is all about immutability. Just simple sample - think what are going to happen if you will use parallel stream.  And in general your first code snippet is kind of sample what to avoid using "functional" approach in java.

Comment: @Divers, you mentioned my first approach? What about the second? It still uses the state of a mutable `Set`, doesn't it? It's not purely functional, cause there are some additional states introduced. I would be glad, if you could demonstrate a *concrete* drawback of any of my approaches.

Comment: It's true, if this was a parallel stream, it would be possible for a data race to allow two objects to be added at the same time, and therefore not filter them. See the duplicate question, which uses a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead.

Comment: Thank you all for your constructive criticism, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Changes applied, now I use `synchronizedSet`.

Comment: Gotcha, will delete that comment as the first part may be opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

You might use a `TreeSet` whose comparator reaches into the subobject's attribute:

```
private static List<Thingy> getUniqueBasedOnDifferentThingyAttr(List<Thingy> originalList) {

    Set<Thingy> uniqueSet = new TreeSet<Thingy>(Comparator.comparing(thingy -> thingy.getNestedThingy().getAttr()));

    return originalList.stream()
            .filter(uniqueSet::add)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

`uniqueSet::add` makes an adequate uniqueness filter because it returns true only if the item is not already in the set.

Comment: Using an original list of length 5 with 3 "unique" items, this solution was, on average, 6 times faster (11.8ms to 66ms) than the originally accepted answer by @GrzegorzGórkiewicz.  I like the use of Comparator as well.

Comment: Imho Hank D's answer should be the accepted one. It's simple and somehow beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

With [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
StreamEx.of(originalList).distinct(e -> e.getNestedThingy().getAttr()).toList();
```

Or by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
Stream.of(originalList).distinct(e -> e.getNestedThingy().getAttr()).toList();
```