# java 8 how to get distinct list on more than one property

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, distinct-values

How can one get the distinct (distinct based on two property) list from a list of objects.
for example let there are list of objects with property name and price.
Now how can I get a list with distinct name or price.
suppose

```
list<xyz> l1 = getlist(); // getlist will return the list.
```

Now let l1 has the following properties(name, price) :-
n1, p1
n1, p2
n2, p1
n2, p3

Now after the filter the list should be-
n1, p1
n2, p3

I tried solving like this -

```
public List<xyz> getFilteredList(List<xyz> l1) {

        return l1
                .stream()
                .filter(distinctByKey(xyz::getName))
                .filter(distinctByKey(xyz::getPrice))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, Object> keyExtractor) {
        Map<Object,Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
    }
```

Now the problem is when i did filter on name the list return would be -
n1, p1
n2, p1

and then it would have run filter on price which return -
n1, p1

which is not the expected result.

Comment: Try flipping your filer statements once.

Comment: if i flip the statement then the case will be similar if list is -
(n1, p1), (n2, p1), (n1,p2),(n3,p2)
then after 1st filter on price will give- (n1, p1), (n1,p2); then on filter on name will give (n1,p1)

Comment: Here are some options: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27872086/3430807

Comment: @Andreas I don't think the problem is to `get the distinct by key`, but instead is how to get first the first mapping: `n1, p1` and then the second `n2, p3`. at least that is not clear for me

Comment: @Eugene they want a list of items that are distinct by both name AND price, which the more I look at it, does not have a trivial solution.

Comment: @NAMS not even that.. it looks like some more like `by price or name, but not already seen`... I don't even know how to phrase that

Comment: @Eugene I think `by price and name, both not already seen` is what they're going for. And in that case, you have to look at both fields simultaneously, not one then the other, like in the OP.

Comment: @NAMS besides keeping two ConcurentHashMaps, one for value and one for price, i see no other way...

Comment: @Eugene I was thinking somewhere along those lines as well. Then you'd have to compare the maps against each other to get the final result.

Answer (score 9):

Almost verbatim from [Stuart Marks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872086/3430807):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Class {

  public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, Object> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
  }

  private static List<Pojo> getList() {
    return Arrays.asList(
      new Pojo("123", 100),
      new Pojo("123", 100),
      new Pojo("123", 100),
      new Pojo("456", 200)
    );
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(getList().stream()
      // extract a key for each Pojo in here. 
      // concatenating name and price together works as an example
      .filter(distinctByKey(p -> p.getName() + p.getPrice()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
  }

}

class Pojo {
  private final String name;
  private final Integer price;

  public Pojo(final String name, final Integer price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public Integer getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Pojo{");
    sb.append("name='").append(name).append('\'');
    sb.append(", price=").append(price);
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

This main method yields:

> [Pojo{name='123', price=100}, Pojo{name='456', price=200}]

#### Edit

Made price an `int` per Eugene's prompting.

Note: that you could use something more interesting as a key if you wanted to flesh it out:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Class {

  public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, Object> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
  }

  private static List<Pojo> getList() {
    return Arrays.asList(
      new Pojo("123", 100),
      new Pojo("123", 100),
      new Pojo("123", 100),
      new Pojo("456", 200)
    );
  }

  private static class NameAndPricePojoKey {
    final String name;
    final int price;

    public NameAndPricePojoKey(final Pojo pojo) {
      this.name = pojo.getName();
      this.price = pojo.getPrice();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

      final NameAndPricePojoKey that = (NameAndPricePojoKey) o;

      if (price != that.price) return false;
      return name != null ? name.equals(that.name) : that.name == null;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
      result = 31 * result + price;
      return result;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(getList().stream()
      // extract a key for each Pojo in here. 
      .filter(distinctByKey(NameAndPricePojoKey::new))
      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
  }

}

class Pojo {
  private String name;
  private Integer price;
  private Object otherField1;
  private Object otherField2;

  public Pojo(final String name, final Integer price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Integer getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public void setPrice(final Integer price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  public Object getOtherField1() {
    return otherField1;
  }

  public void setOtherField1(final Object otherField1) {
    this.otherField1 = otherField1;
  }

  public Object getOtherField2() {
    return otherField2;
  }

  public void setOtherField2(final Object otherField2) {
    this.otherField2 = otherField2;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    final Pojo pojo = (Pojo) o;

    if (name != null ? !name.equals(pojo.name) : pojo.name != null) return false;
    if (price != null ? !price.equals(pojo.price) : pojo.price != null) return false;
    if (otherField1 != null ? !otherField1.equals(pojo.otherField1) : pojo.otherField1 != null) return false;
    return otherField2 != null ? otherField2.equals(pojo.otherField2) : pojo.otherField2 == null;

  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (price != null ? price.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (otherField1 != null ? otherField1.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (otherField2 != null ? otherField2.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Pojo{");
    sb.append("name='").append(name).append('\'');
    sb.append(", price=").append(price);
    sb.append(", otherField1=").append(otherField1);
    sb.append(", otherField2=").append(otherField2);
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this quite does it. This gets a list of all distinct combinations of price and name together, which might be a good first step. Price is probably a double, but since it gets concatenated with the name, it shouldn't make a difference anyway.

Comment: Given that distinctByKey() returns a Predicate<T>, can and() / or() methods be used to compose distinctByKey with another predicate? E.g. when I use distinctByKey(e -> e.getName()).or() it tells that or() expects Predicate(? super Object) and not ? super T.

Comment: NB if I use my type instead of the generic parameter T, e.g. Predicate<Pojo> distinctByKey(Function<? super Pojo, ? > keyExtractor), then it resolves or(Predicate <? super Pojo>) and I can compose multiple predicates using and() / or().

Answer (score 6):

I'd go for something like this, which is fairly simple and flexible, and builds on your example:

```java
public static <T> List<T> distinctList(List<T> list, Function<? super T, ?>... keyExtractors) {

    return list
        .stream()
        .filter(distinctByKeys(keyExtractors))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKeys(Function<? super T, ?>... keyExtractors) {

    final Map<List<?>, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    return t -> {

        final List<?> keys = Arrays.stream(keyExtractors)
            .map(ke -> ke.apply(t))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return seen.putIfAbsent(keys, Boolean.TRUE) == null;

    };

}
```

This can then be called in the following manner:

```
final List<Xyz> distinct = distinctList(list, Xyz::getName, Xyz::getPrice)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution based on the class `Item` which defines a `name` and a `price`:

```
public class Item {

    public String name;
    public double price;

    Item(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

The requirement is to obtain only `Item`s from a given `List<Item>` which have distinct `name`s **and** distinct `price`s, in the order in which they occur.

I catch this requirement of being distinct by a class `ItemWrapper`:

```
public class ItemWrapper {

    Item item;

    ItemWrapper(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof ItemWrapper)) return false;
        ItemWrapper other = (ItemWrapper) obj;
        return  Objects.equals(item.name, other.item.name) ||
                item.price == other.item.price;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Now we have everything in place to filter a given `List<Item>` of items:

```
List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
        new Item("name-1", 100.00),
        new Item("name-1", 555.00),
        new Item("name-2", 100.00),
        new Item("name-2", 999.99),
        new Item("name-3", 100.00),
        new Item("name-4", 555.00),
        new Item("name-5", 999.99)
);
```

as following:

```
items.stream()
     .map(item -> new ItemWrapper(item))
     .distinct()
     .map(wrapper -> wrapper.item)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The items captured are:

- name=name-1, price=100.0
- name=name-2, price=999.99
- name=name-4, price=555.0

Comment: what is wrapper?

Comment: The class `ItemWrapper` implements the method `equals(Object obj)` which enforces the requirement to treat two `Items` as equal if they share either the same `name` or the same `price`. I moved this logic into a separate class because it did not seam to be natural to the domain class `Item`. Does this comment answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Why not that way:

```
@Value
static class User {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    var user1 = new User("firstName1", "lastName1", 20);
    var user2 = new User("firstName1", "lastName2", 20);
    var user3 = new User("firstName3", "lastName3", 30);

    var users = List.of(user1, user2, user3);

    var uniqueByFirstNameAndAge = users
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(usr -> Set.of(usr.getFirstName(), usr.getAge()), Function.identity(), (usr1, usr2) -> usr1))
        .values();

    System.out.println(uniqueByFirstNameAndAge);


}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).