# Convert a List<Object> to a Map<String, List<Object>> and distinct the duplicates according to some properties of List's element?

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-stream, functional-interface

For example, for two classes like this:

```
Class RawItem {
    private String category;
    private int code;
    private String name;
}

Class Item {
    private int code;
    private String name;
}
```

And list of RawItem as following:

> [
>     {
>         "category":"a",
>         "code":1,
>         "name":"item1"
>      },
>      {
>         "category":"a",
>         "code":1,
>         "name":"item1"
>      },
>      {
>         "category":"a",
>         "code":2,
>         "name":"item2"
>      },
>      {
>         "category":"b",
>         "code":1,
>         "name":"item1"
>      },
>      {
>         "category":"b",
>         "code":1,
>         "name":"item1"
>      }
>   ]

Turn it to a `Map<String, List<Item>>` like this:

```
{
   "a":[
      {
         "code":1,
         "name":"item1"
      },
      {
         "code":2,
         "name":"item2"
      }
   ],
   "b":[
      {
         "code":1,
         "name":"item1"
      }
   ]
}
```

Any reply will be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Please post your attempt

Comment: If it is mostly code then you should consider describing your problem more, telling where did you find the problem (which would require posting your attempt)

Comment: `List<RawItem>` to `Map<String, Set<Item>>` would be nicest though `Item` would need equals+hashCode.

Comment: I need to preserve the order of the original list

Comment: It is mostly code because I quoted some non-code as code, that’s it. The problem is already described clearly

Comment: And I don’t know how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `groupingBy` should work.
As part of your additional requirements, we know that the `equals` method of `RawItem` objects cannot be used, which is why we are using a filter instead of the `Stream` `distinct` method (*):

```
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    Map<String, List<Item>> m = 
       l.stream()
        .filter(item -> seen.add(item.category + ":" + item.name + ":" + item.code))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.category,
            Collectors.mapping(item -> new Item(item.code, item.name), 
                               Collectors.toList())));
```

Note that in order to allow the method `distinct` to work and remove duplicates, you need to have a proper implementation of the `hashCode` and `equals` methods in the `RawItem` class.

As an example, the following test:

```
List<RawItem> list = Arrays.asList(new RawItem("a", 1, "dfg"),
                                   new RawItem("a", 1, "dfg"),
                                   new RawItem("a", 1, "fdgdfdfgdg"),
                                   new RawItem("b", 1, "dfg"));

Map<String, List<Item>> map = // the above

System.out.println(map);
```

gives

```
{
   a=[Item{code=1, name='dfg'}, Item{code=1, name='fdgdfdfgdg'}],
   b=[Item{code=1, name='dfg'}]
}
```

**(*) Edit:**
As shared by the OP, the following posts help to design a solution based on a custom equivalence relationship with the stream API, when `distinct()` cannot be used:

- [Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23699371/926701)
- [Java Lambda Stream Distinct() on arbitrary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27870136/926701)
- [Java 8 how to get distinct list on more than one property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42817884/926701)

Comment: This does not fully solve the problem since it does not get rid of items with identical content (duplicates)

Comment: @ClaudiuGuja Indeed, fixed the post.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response, I will try it tmrw because I already off my work after I asked this question, I’m using my phone to commenting now...but since distinct() need a proper implementation of equals, I doubt if it works since I can’t use category, code, name to uniquely identify a RawItem, it have other key fields that not listed here. So any other solution as a supplementary?

Comment: @Wuaner: Sure, I updated the post to take into account this additional requirement

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez So brilliant~ can’t test it now since no computer around, but I know it will work! Accepted and thanks again.

Comment: It works~ saved my day, and I extract the Set  _seen_ as a Predicate as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/1635855)  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872086/1635855)  [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42819145/1635855)  illustrated.

Comment: @Wuaner Thank you for the feedback, I added these references to the post. I can also update it to replace the set *seen* with a predicate as you mention?

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez I already done my work with predicate, but it would be great if we post it here for some others, I think?. Many thanks for this solution, btw.