# Elegantly combine elements of two lists so that they are unique in a certain property value?

Tags: java, java-8

Suppose I have this Java 8 code:

```
public class Foo {
    private long id;
    public getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //--snip--
}


//Somewhere else...

List<Foo> listA = getListA();
List<Foo> listB = getListB();

List<Foo> uniqueFoos = ???;
```

In `List<Foo> uniqueFoos` I want to add all elements of `listA` and `listB` so all `Foo`s have unique IDs. I.e. if there is already a `Foo` in `uniqueFoos` that has a particular ID don't add another `Foo` with the same ID but skip it instead.

Of course there is plain old iteration, but I think there should be something more elegant (probably involving streams, but not mandatory), but I can't quite figure it out...

I can think of good solutions involving an override of the `equals()` method to basically `return id == other.id;` and using a `Set` or `distinct()`. Unfortunately I can't override `equals()` because object equality must not change.

What is a clear and efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: `List<Foo> uniqueFoos = Stream.concat(listA.stream(), listB.stream()) .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId, Function.identity(), (a,b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new), m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));`

Comment: that can be debatable, but code apparent simplicity is not elegance to me. A simple iteration is easily identifiable, understandable and doesn't perform unwanted extra actions, even if code is longer. I find them elegant. And you don't loose time for this on SO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java 8 how to get distinct list on more than one property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817884/java-8-how-to-get-distinct-list-on-more-than-one-property)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

```
Collection<Foo> uniqueFoos = Stream.concat(listA.stream(), listB.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Foo::getId,
        f -> f,
        (oldFoo, newFoo) -> oldFoo))
    .values();
```

If you need a `List` instead of a `Collection`, simply do:

```
List<Foo> listUniqueFoos = new ArrayList<>(uniqueFoos);
```

---

If you also need to preserve encounter order of elements, you can use the overloaded version of [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) that accepts a `Supplier` for the returned map:

```
Collection<Foo> uniqueFoos = Stream.concat(listA.stream(), listB.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Foo::getId,
        f -> f,
        (oldFoo, newFoo) -> oldFoo,
        LinkedHashMap::new))
    .values();
```

---

I think it's worth adding a non-stream variant:

```
Map<Long, Foo> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
listA.forEach(f -> map.merge(g.getId(), f, (oldFoo, newFoo) -> oldFoo));
listB.forEach(f -> map.merge(g.getId(), f, (oldFoo, newFoo) -> oldFoo));

Collection<Foo> uniqueFoos = map.values();
```

This could be refactored into a generic method to not repeat code:

```
static <T, K> Collection<T> uniqueBy(Function<T, K> groupBy, List<T>... lists) {
    Map<K, T> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (List<T> l : lists) {
        l.forEach(e -> map.merge(groupBy.apply(e), e, (o, n) -> o));
    }
    return map.values();
}
```

Which you can use as follows:

```
Collection<Foo> uniqueFoos = uniqueBy(Foo::getId, listA, listB);
```

This approach uses the [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) method.

Comment: And you can get the values and collect as list

Comment: I think that should be fine since the OP wanted `List<Foo> uniqueFoos`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do.

```
 List<Foo> uniqueFoos = Stream.concat(listA.stream(), listB.stream())
                              .filter(distinctByKey(Foo::getId))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());


 public <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write this one. This skips the second and next elements that have the same id thanks to `filter()` and the use of a Set that stores the encountered ids :

```
    Set<Long> ids = new HashSet<>();
    List<Foo> uniqueFoos = Stream.concat(getListA().stream(), getListB().stream())
                                 .filter(f -> ids.add(f.getId()))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It is not a full stream solution but it is rather straight and readable.