# Java Streams: distinct() on a pre-sorted stream?

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806467/java-streams-how-to-do-an-efficient-distinct-and-sort), the implementation of `distinct()` is able to use a more efficient algorithm when the stream it operates on is known by the runtime to be sorted.  How can we achieve a similar result if *we* know that the stream is sorted (e.g. because it came from an externally pre-sorted data source, such as an SQL query with an `order by` clause) but isn't flagged as such?  There's an `unordered()` operation that removes the ordering flags, but as far as I can see no way of telling the system that the data has been ordered externally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your spliterator around an existing collection for example:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

    Spliterator<Integer> sp = Spliterators.spliterator(list, Spliterator.SORTED);

    System.out.println(sp.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED)); // true
```

Comment: The streams I'm using are produced by a third party library, so I don't create spliterators myself at all.  I guess I *could* use some kind of proxy spliterator, which might work.

Comment: Yeah, a wrapping spliterator reporting different characteristics seems to be the only solution.