# Java Stream Map List to Set and preserve Order

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an **Answer** class and an **User** class.

Answer has a `getUser()` and User has a `getPoints()`

From a list of Answer I would like to get a HashSet of User sorted by points. I tried following:

```
 Set<User> collectSet = list.stream().map(Answer::getUser)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getPoints))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

 collectSet.forEach(a -> System.out.println(a.toString()));
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to preserve the order. The output is always different.

Interesting is that the same example with list does work correctly

```
List<User> collectList = list.stream().map(Answer::getUser)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getPoints))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

collectList.forEach(a -> System.out.println(a.toString()));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A HashSet doesn't have any order. If you want to preserve insertion order, use a List, or a LinkedHashSet

Comment: I don't want any duplicate elements. That's why I need a set.

Comment: then use `.distinct()`

Comment: And what do you think a LinkedHashSet is? Why don't you read the javadoc?

Comment: [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is not deterministic. Use at least [`forEachOrdered`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) does not preserve the insertion order but [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) does. You can try with [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead.

**Edit:**
An other alternative is to use a [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). It's a set so the duplicated values are deleted. And the elements are sorted when they are inserted. The sort is made using the method `compareTo` (provided by the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface).
For example :

```
// Answer class
public class Answer {

    private final User user;

    public Answer(final User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}

// User class
public class User implements Comparable<User> {

    private final int points;

    public User(final int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(User other) {
        // Sort user by their points (ascending order)
        return points - other.points;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" + "points=" + points + '}';
    }
}
```

Then in your main code :

```
// Main
List<Answer> answers = Arrays.asList(
    new Answer(new User(0)),
    new Answer(new User(20)),
    new Answer(new User(1)),
    new Answer(new User(20)),
    new Answer(new User(10))
);

answers
    .stream()
    .map(Answer::getUser)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output :

```
User{points=0}
User{points=1}
User{points=10}
User{points=20}
```

Comment: This code only works as long as a user only consists of the points property. In real life scenarios, you surely don’t want to consider all users having the same points value as equal, which is what what will happen with `TreeSet` here.

Answer (score 5):

```
 Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)
```

First you are sorting those entries according to some `Comparator` - giving them "some" order, but then you put them into a `HashSet` (order is broken), thus different results. Use `LinkedHashSet` to collect them in order to preserve the sorting order.

If you still want to collect them to a `List`, you can:

```
 yourList.stream()
         .sorted(....)
         .distinct() 
         .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

The order of the operations themselves (`distinct` vs `sorted`) [matters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806467/java-streams-how-to-do-an-efficient-distinct-and-sort)

Comment: `assuming hashcode/equals implemented` should also be assumed when just using a plain old `Set`

Comment: @Lino :) right, will edit

Comment: The order of `distinct` and `sorted` only matters for the natural order, which should be compatible with the equality. For a custom comparator, like the OP’s one comparing only the “points” property, the order can not be used to optimize the `distinct` operation.

Comment: @Holger oh! I guess i never understood it than... thank you!

Comment: Thinking about it, it would be possible to optimize this too, but it would be a different algorithm than the one currently used for the natural order.

Comment: @Holger since you said you don't mind on a previous such request... would you provide your input here also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070380/local-type-inference-vs-instance/49071129#49071129

Answer (score 1):

May be you want to use `TreeSet`.

Two users with same no. of points are not equal, So there should be some `uniqueId` for user.

I am considering it as `userId`

No `hashCode`, `equals` required here ( but good to have, see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) ) as `TreeSet` uses `Comparator` ( alternatively `User` class can implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) ) to determine whether two elements are equal or not.

```
TreeSet<User> users = answers.stream()
    .map(Answer::getUser)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<User>(
       Comparator.comparingInt(User::getPoints).thenComparing(User::getUserId))));
```