# How extract sorted list of distinct integers from a Set of objects using Java streams?

Tags: java

I have a set of value objects:

```
Set<EntityKey> clientAssignedPlaceholderEntityKeys
```

Where the EntityKey class has the following properties:

```
private Integer objectRef;
private String entityType;
```

What is the most efficient way to extract the distinct objectRef values into a sorted list using streams?

I have the following but the fact that it calls stream() twice seems like a bad smell:

```
  // Extract into a sorted list all the distinct placeholder objectRefs (regardless of type).
  List<Integer> sortedPlaceholderObjectRefs = clientAssignedPlaceholderEntityKeys.stream()
          .map(entityKey -> entityKey.getObjectRef())
          .collect(Collectors.toSet())
          .stream()  // having to call stream() a 2nd time here feels sub-optimal
          .sorted()
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm sure It's possible with single stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      clientAssignedPlaceholderEntityKeys.stream()
                                         .map(ek -> ek.getObjectRef())
                                         .sorted()
                                         .distinct()
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Regarding your doubt about the order of **sorted()** and **distinct()**

Quoting the very first answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806467/java-streams-how-to-do-an-efficient-distinct-and-sort):
Chaining **distinct()** operation after **sorted()**, the implementation will utilize the sorted nature of the data and avoid building an internal HashSet.

Comment: That's good to know @redshift. 
In case future readers might get confused, could you please edit your answer to show distinct() operation after sorted()? I will then accept this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe:

```
sortedPlaceholderObjectRefs = clientAssignedPlaceholderEntityKeys.stream()
                      .map(entityKey -> entityKey.getObjectRef())
                      .sorted()
                      .distinct()
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT:**

calling `.distinct()` before `.sorted()` might be more optimal

Comment: I like the look of that but wonder if it might be more efficient if distinct() were done before sorted()?

Comment: Yes, i was just editing my comment to change that. It should be more optimal

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Integer> sortedRefs = clientAssignedPlaceholderEntityKeys
                      .stream()
                      .map(EntityKey::getObjectRef)
                      .distinct()
                      .sorted()
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```