# Java 8 Streams Remove Duplicate Letter

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to apply my knowledge of streams to some leetcode algorithm questions. Here is a general summary of the question:

> Given a string which contains only lowercase letters, remove duplicate
> letters so that every letter appears once and only once. You must make
> sure your result is the smallest in lexicographical order among all
> possible results.

Example:

```
Input: "bcabc"
Output: "abc"
```

Another example:

```
Input: "cbacdcbc"
Output: "acdb"
```

This seemed like a simple problem, just stream the values into a new list from the string, sort the values, find the distinct values, and then throw it back into a list, and append the list's value to a string. Here is what I came up with:

```
public String removeDuplicateLetters(String s)
{
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(char ch : c) 
    {
        list.add(ch);
    }
    
    List<Character> newVal = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()); 
    String newStr = "";
    for(char ch : newVal) 
    {
        newStr += ch;
    }
    
    return newStr;
}
```

The first example is working perfectly, but instead of "acdb" for the second output, I'm getting "abcd". Why would abcd not be the least lexicographical order? Thanks!

Comment: yeah i'm aware of that, i was kind of looking to see if I can get it with streams based practice

Comment: what exactly is the question? the order isn't correct or that the expected output is not what you think it should be? what is it from streams that you are looking for?

Comment: What is the order in 2nd example  output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I had pointed out in the comments using a `LinkedHashSet` would be best here, but for the `Stream`s practice you could do this:

```
public static String removeDuplicateLetters(String s) {
    return s.chars().sorted().distinct().collect(
        StringBuilder::new,
        StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
        StringBuilder::append
    ).toString();
}
```

Note: `distinct()` comes after `sorted()` in order to optimize the stream, see Holger's explanation in the comments as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43807329/5319267).

Lot of different things here so I'll number them:

1. You can stream the characters of a `String` using `String#chars()` instead of making a `List` where you add all the characters.
2. To ensure that the resulting string is smallest in lexographical order, we can sort the `IntStream`.
3. We can convert the `IntStream` back to a `String` by performing a [mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) with a `StringBuilder`. We then convert this `StringBuilder` to our desired string.

A mutable reduction is the `Stream` way of doing the equivalent of something like:

```
for (char ch : newVal) {
    newStr += ch;
}
```

However, this has the added benefit of using a `StringBuilder` for concatenation instead of a `String`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1532483/5319267) as to why this is more performant.

For the actual question you have about the conflict of expected vs. observed output: I believe `abcd` is the right answer for the second output, since it is the smallest in lexographical order.

Comment: With the current version of the reference implementation, `.sorted().distinct()` is more efficient than `.distinct().sorted()`, because the subsequent distinct op will utilize the sorted nature of the data.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "cbacdcbc";
    string.chars()
            .mapToObj(item -> (char) item)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()).forEach(System.out::print);

}
```

the output：abcd，hope help you!

Answer (score 0):

//1st Approach

```
String input = "aabscs";
Arrays.stream(input.split(""))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet()).forEach(System.out::print);
```

//2nd Approach

```
input.chars()
            .mapToObj(item -> (char) item)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()).forEach(System.out::print);
```

//Output: absc

/**
It can be done in multiple ways, we can also use Map, but I think this is a simple one.

Hope it will help you
*/

Answer (score 0):

```java
List<String> c = Arrays
  .asList("helloword".split(""))
  .stream()
  .distinct()
  .toList();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).