# How Predicate maintain state in Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am looking at this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872086/8793235) and trying to understand the following piece of code.

## copied from Stuart Marks answer

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T,Object> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object,Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}

BigDecimal totalShare = orders.stream()
    .filter(distinctByKey(o -> o.getCompany().getId()))
    .map(Order::getShare)
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

My question here is everytime **distinctByKey** will be called and resulting new **ConcurrentHashMap**. how it is maintaining the state using **new ConcurrentHashMap<>();** ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since this is a capturing lambda, indeed a new `Predicate` instance will be returned all the time on each call to `distinctByKey`; but this will happen per entire stream, not per each individual element.

If you are willing to run your example with:

`Djdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses=/Your/Path/Here`

you would see that a `class` is generated for your the implementation of the `Predicate`. Because this is a stateful lambda - it captures the `CHM` and `Function`, it will have a `private` constructor and a `static factory method` that returns an instance.

---

Each call of `distinctByKey` will produce a different instance, but that instance will be reused for each element of the Stream. Things might be a bit more obvious if you run this example:

```
 public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T,Object> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object,Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    Predicate<T> predicate =  t -> {
        Object obj = keyExtractor.apply(t);
        System.out.println("stream element : " + obj);
        return seen.putIfAbsent(obj, Boolean.TRUE) == null;
    };

    System.out.println("Predicate with hash :" + predicate.hashCode());
    return predicate;
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
static class User {
    private final String name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.of(new User("a"), new User("b"))
          .filter(distinctByKey(User::getName))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

This will output:

```
Predicate with hash :1259475182
stream element : a
stream element : b
```

A single `Predicate` for both elements of the Stream.

If you add another `filter`:

```
Stream.of(new User("a"), new User("b"))
      .filter(distinctByKey(User::getName))
      .filter(distinctByKey(User::getName))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There will be two `Predicate`s:

```
Predicate with hash :1259475182
Predicate with hash :1072591677
stream element : a
stream element : a
stream element : b
stream element : b
```

Comment: A different instance of the Predicate for each stream element? No, there's one CHM and one Predicate per call to `distinctByKey`.

Comment: @StuartMarks wouldnt `get$Lambda` return a new Predicate all the time when it is called?

Comment: Sure, but `get$Lambda()` should only be called when the lambda expression is evaluated, that is, from within the call to `distinctByKey`. Each stream element that's passed through filter will call the same lambda instance's `test()` method. It's that instance that holds the captured CHM and keyExtractor function.

Answer (score 6):

It seems pretty confusing but it’s quite simple. What actually happens is that the `distinctByKey` method is called *only once* so there will only ever be one instance of the `ConcurrentHashMap` and it’s captured by the lambda expression. So when the `distinctByKey` method returns a `Predicate` object we then apply that to every element of the stream.

Comment: Is it true for parallelStream() ?

Comment: @xyz: don’t get confused by the fact that there’s a stream use. Just look at the *code structure*. You have `a().b(c()).d().e()`, so the methods are invoked in the order `a`, `c`, `b` (receiving the result of `c`), `d`, `e`. The `a` method is `stream`, `c` is `distinctByKey`, `b` is `filter`, etc., but the actual stream operation is only started with `e`, which is `reduce`. The other four methods have been invoked and completed before that.

Comment: @xyz the same applies.

Comment: @Aominè indeed that method will be called only once, but there will be *multiple* instances of the `Predicate` returned

Comment: @Aominè no worries - it gets even funner when you think of the bootstrap method that get's called only once, a `CallSite` that wraps a `MethodHandle` to the `get$Lambda` method build by `ASM` linked only once, it's crazy how many details there are