# Get unique items from List of Objects with a Set in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

my people object looks like this

```
class People {
   this.name,
   this.height,
   this.age
}
```

I have a list from a database query like so

```
List<People> people = DAO.queryAllPeople();
```

which returns 100's of people

Then I want just people with unique height

```
    Set<People> uniquePeople = list
                    .stream()
                    .map(people -> people)
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .collect( Collectors.toSet() );
```

But this is returning all objects, is there a way to get people distinct by height?

Edit this is what I want but I want the Person object so I can call get methods when I loop over it

```
  Set<String> people =      people
                                .stream()
                                .map(People::getHeight)
                                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                .collect( Collectors.toSet() );
```

Comment: That class, is it even compiling? The members are missing the types and `this` is not possible at that position.

Comment: `.map(people -> people)` What did you expect this to do?

Comment: Can you show some examples? Give some example inputs, desired output and current output. In the current state your question is too **unclear** in my opinion. Useful read: [mcve].

Comment: updated my original for an example of what i'd want

Comment: This solution should do the trick for you, my friend. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870136/java-lambda-stream-distinct-on-arbitrary-key/27872086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, naming a class `People` is not natural, a better name would be `Person`.

As, for solving your problem, you can override `equals` and `hashcode` for `height` only like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
     if (this == o) return true;
     if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

     Person person = (Person) o;

     return height == person.height;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
     return height;
}
```

The above assumes height is an `int` field. if instead, it's `Integer`, then you'll need to implement it like so:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

      Person person = (Person) o;

      return height != null ? height.equals(person.height) : person1.height == null;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
     return height != null ? height.hashCode() : 0;
}
```

Now, you can do:

```
 Set<People> uniquePeople = 
              myList.stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

or for what ever reason you don't want to override `equals` and `hashcode` you can do it with [the `toMap` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-).

```
Set<Person> values = new HashSet<>(myList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getHeight, Function.identity(),
                        (left, right) -> left))
                .values());
```

deciphering the above code snippet:

```
myList.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getHeight, Function.identity(),
              (left, right) -> left))
      .values()
```

This creates a stream from `myList` collecting it to a map implementation, where `Person::getHeight` is a function extracting the person height for the map keys, `Function.identity()` is a function extracting a person object for the map values, `(left, right) -> left)` is known as the merge function meaning if two given people have the same key (height) we return the first person (`left`). Conversely, `(left, right) -> right` will return the last person in the case of key conflict.

Lastly, we pass the result of this processing to the `HashSet` constructor to create a `Set<Person>`.

Comment: This gives unique heights with random people assigned, @Garuuk asked for people with unique height, meaning there is no other person with the same height.

Comment: @hoaz _"This gives unique heights with random people assigned"_ , what do you mean? _@Garuuk asked for people with unique height, meaning there is no other person with the same height._ that's exactly what this code does...

Comment: This does give unique heights, it works. Also Aomine, could you explain what the left, right -> left means?

Comment: Thanks Aomine, I appreciate it. Also, lastly, if I wanted to filter out nulls any Height that is null do I do that before the .collect method?

Comment: @Garuuk  you can filter out null elements from `myList` and person objects that have null `Height` like this `Set<Person> values = new HashSet<>(myList.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull) 
                .filter(p -> p.getHeight() != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getHeight, Function.identity(),
                        (left, right) -> left))
                .values());`

Comment: if you only want to filter out person objects that have null Height `Set<Person> values = new HashSet<>(myList.stream() .filter(p -> p.getHeight() != null) .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getHeight, Function.identity(), (left, right) -> left)) .values());`

Comment: Given John is 5 feet and Mike is 5 feet as well. There are no persons with unique height in this list. But if he really wants unique heights and somone with this height, then this solution is non-deterministic

Comment: @hoaz I believe the OP wants _distinct by height_. i.e. in the example, you've provided John should be in the result set but not Mike.

Comment: Correct, I should have been clear with my verbage. Distinct height is what I wanted - I'll update my OP. Thank you very much for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Split this task into two subtasks.

First group people by height:

```
Map<Integer, List<People>> groups = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(People::getHeight);
```

Then find which groups have only one person:

```
groups.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() == 1) // use only groups with one person
        .map(e -> e.getValue().get(0))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```