# Java 8 predicates using methods bodies are called only once?

Tags: java, java-8, predicate

I have examined the following snippet:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> computed = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();/*IS THIS LINE CALLED ONCE ON STREAM->FILTER NOT MATTER HOW LONG THE STREAM IS*/
    return t -> {return computed.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;};
}

private void test(){
    final long d = Stream.of("JOHN","STEPHEN","ORTIZ","RONDON")
            .filter(distinctByKey(Function.identity()))
            .count();
    System.out.println("d = " + d);
}
```

This code is not mine. I know that using a `ConcurrentMap` is not the right choice in this example and I should use `ConcurrentMap` instead of `Map` in this case, but this is not my concern now.

I thought that the `distinctByKey` method is called or interpreted in each iteration of the `Stream`. I mean the `Map` being instantiated in each turn, but it's not!

Is the body of the `Predicate` method called only once?

In the `Stream` iteration, is this an assertion?

Because when I try the following code:

```
final Function<String,Integer>a = (name)->name.length();
System.out.println(distinctByKey(a).test("JOHN"));
System.out.println(distinctByKey(a).test("STEPHEN"));
System.out.println(distinctByKey(a).test("ORTIZ"));
System.out.println(distinctByKey(a).test("RONDON"));
```

I can see that the body of the method is indeed called in each line. What makes the body of the filter to only be called once?

Comment: I think you've taken your code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/5515060), and when reading his other [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872086/5515060) it should probably clear up. `distinctByKey()` is only called **once**. But the predicate it returns is called for **every** element.

Comment: hey mate i found this code on the project i am working perhaps was copied back then

Comment: And honestly: consider to rewrite your question around the [mcve] topic. Like: what is the point of having a `test()` method print something ... went that print out doesnt show anywhere. And worse: having that method named test ... which kinda gets really confusing given that you then call predicate `test()` methods as well).

Comment: What do you mean with “I know that using a `ConcurrentMap` is not the right choice in this example and I should use `ConcurrentMap` …”? This doesn’t make any sense. Besides that, `t -> {return computed.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;}` is unnecessarily complicated. You can simply write `t -> computed.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `.filter(distinctByKey(Function.identity()))`, the argument passed to `filter()` is evaluated. That's the only time `distinctByKey(Function.identity())` is executed and returns an instance of `Predicate<String>`.

That `Predicate` is then evaluated (i.e. it's `test()` method is executed) multiple times, each time for a different element of the `Stream`.

To make your last snippet behave similar to the `Stream` pipeline, it should look like this:

```
final Function<String,Integer> a = (name)->name.length();
Predicate<String> pred = distinctByKey(a);
System.out.println(pred.test("JOHN"));
System.out.println(pred.test("STEPHEN"));
System.out.println(pred.test("ORTIZ"));
System.out.println(pred.test("RONDON"));
```

Comment: yep that was the way i thougt it work. but i face this snippet and i said the Map is instance of every turn but i was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

`distinctByKey` returns a *single* instance of the `Predicate` that caches the `ConcurrentHashMap`. You could achieve almost the same thing if you replace the creation of the `Predicate` via the lambda with an anonymous inner class for example.

Answer (score 4):

> I thought that the distinctByKey method is called or interpreted in
>   each iteration of the Stream i mean the Map being instance in each
>   turn but it's not! my question is the body of the Predicate method
>   call only one time? in the Stream iteration is this a assertion?

No.  Streams are not magic, and they do not overthrow standard Java semantics.  Consider the code presented:

> ```
>     final long d = Stream.of("JOHN","STEPHEN","ORTIZ","RONDON")
>             .filter(distinctByKey(Function.identity()))
>             .count();
> ```

Taking specific types and methods out of the picture, that has this general form:

```
long x = A.b(y).c(z).d(w);
```

There's no reason to expect that any of `a()`, `b()`, or `c()` is invoked more than once in that chain, and or that their arguments are evaluated more than once each. That is not affected by some of the types being `Stream`.

What happens instead in your case is that the `Predicate` returned by (the sole invocation of) your `distinctByKey()` method is *used* more than once as the stream in which it is embedded is processed.  That `Predicate` contains a reference to a `Map`, which it uses and modifies in performing its work.