# How to filter a list with same date value using java streams

Tags: spring, filter, stream, datefield

I would like to filter a list of T class objects having which is having date fields using java 8 stream.The date is of type LocalDateTime , i want to compare the dates. If there are two records with the same date has to be removed from the list only one has to be retained , duplicate records with the same dates has to be removed.

i tried Filter method of streams which is not working as expected.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example ? or what you have already tried and so se will be able to help you.

Comment: Include the data structure you are comparing and the code you have written that doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)

Comment: I will try , thank you

Comment: Is using a stream a requirement? You can eliminate duplicates by a property value using other avenues.

Comment: Also duplicate of [*Java Lambda Stream Distinct() on arbitrary key?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27870136/642706)

Comment: See especially these two Answers by [Stuart Marks](https://www.linkedin.com/in/stuart-marks-17a71a2): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872086/642706) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/642706).

Comment: The Java team is working to let us define intermediate operations on a stream. Just as [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html) lets us define a terminal operation on a stream, `Gatherer` will do the same for intermediate operation. I imagine this might help with the problem raised by this Question.  See video presentation on YouTube: [*Better Java Streams with Gatherers - Inside Java Newscast #57*](https://youtu.be/epgJm2dZTSg?si=bCrUCahhFcBagK3k). See also [*JEP 461: Stream Gatherers (Preview)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461)