# What is the simplest way to make a Java List<User> become unique?

Tags: java

We got these codes:

```
User user1=new User();
user1.setUserName("tomhand");

User user2=new User();
user2.setUserName("mira");

User user3=new User();
user3.setUserName("tomhand");

.......

List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
list.add(user1);
list.add(user2);
list.add(user3);
....
```

We can see that `list` contains 2 `User`s that have same user name `tomhand`
Now, What is the simplest way to make the `list` become unique (ie, the `list` should not contain 2 users that have the same UserName)?

Comment: Use a `Set` and Override `equals` and `hashCode` in the `User` class.

Comment: One thing to note here is that putting mutable values into a hash-based set is not a good idea: changing properties of the values which change the hash code would invalidate the invariants of `HashSet`.

Comment: use this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/3215527 if you cannot/want not implement `equals` based on user name.

Comment: It's not a good idea to do this with mutable objects, since the user names could be changed after adding them to the list. This would require the observer pattern or some similar code to be used to be notified of such changes to check again, if a user name occurs more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When add elements to the list (`ArrayList`) it does not perform any check on the existing element to check whether it is new element or already present. It will not be possible to use `List` and get the desired behavior directly.

You can use the `Set` collection for storing only the unique `User` instance based on the `name` attribute of it.

It is using the `HashSet<User>` implementation, which uses the `hashcode()` of the incoming object for storing them at a certain location. If the element is already present then it uses the `equals()` to compare the two objects.

Here is an sample example:

```
public class User {
  private String name;
  public User(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof User))
      return false;
    User user = (User) obj;
    return user.name.equals(this.name);
  }
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode()  ;
  }
}

class UserMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<User> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(new User("A"));
    set.add(new User("B"));
    set.add(new User("A"));
    System.out.println(set.size());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `Comparable` interface in your `User` class and then use a `Set<User>` collection

Comment: Is the `hashCode()` and `equals()` pair not sufficient?

Comment: If you're implementing `Comparable` you need to use a `TreeSet`. For `HashSet` you need `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: [The ordering needs to be consistent with equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) for `TreeSet`, so you'd likely need to implement both; however, it is not necessary to define an ordering using `Comparable` simply to get uniqueness, since you can just use an unordered set like `HashSet`.

Comment: @MrHug only the OP can respond to it: the Comparable interface garantee you also the ordering (in certain collections)

Comment: Fair enough, it depends on the Set implementation as pointed out by @Kayaman

Comment: @AndyTurner "The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface." i.e. it will work, it will just be a rebel that doesn't care about contracts!

Comment: I am getting how `Comparable` can achieve the De-duplication here. It used for sorting the data. It needs the `equals()` and `hashCode()` as specified by @MrHug.

Answer (score -1):

Simple way use a Set, you'll have to overwrite equals and hashCode. Example 
[Whenever you implement equals, you MUST also implement hashCode](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/)

```
public class User
{
private String username;
//other fields comes here

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((username == null) ? 0 : username.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    User other = (User) obj;
    if (username == null)
    {
        if (other.username != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!username.equals(other.username))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public String getUsername()
{
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username)
{
    this.username = username;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "User [username=" + username + "]";
}


public static void main(String args[])
{
    Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
    User user1=new User();
    user1.setUsername("tomhand");

    User user2=new User();
    user2.setUsername("mira");

    User user3=new User();
    user3.setUsername("tomhand");

    users.add(user1);
    users.add(user2);
    users.add(user3);

    System.out.println(users);

}
 }
```