# Printing a list (without repeated items) with lambda expressions in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

### What do I have

I have three classes. `Main.java`, `Producto.java`, and `Supermercado.java`.

- `Main.java` contains the main.
- `Producto.java` the product structure I want to print in my list.
- `Supermercado.java` is a Singleton Pattern which represents the supermarket where my List is placed.

### The code

I will show you guys only the code I think is related to the question, if you need more information please do not hesitate to ask.

**Main.java**

```
// Instanciar productos
Producto p1 = new Producto("Sal 100gr",  LocalDate.now(), 0.5f, 1);
Producto p2 = new Producto("Pimienta 25gr",  LocalDate.now(), 0.2f, 1);
Producto p3 = new Producto("Sal 1kg",  LocalDate.now(), 2, 1);
Producto p4 = new Producto("Te limón", LocalDate.now(), 3.5f, 2);
Producto p5 = new Producto("Azucar 1kg", LocalDate.now(), 2, 1);
Producto p6 = new Producto("Azucar 5kg", LocalDate.now(), 10, 1);
Producto p7 = new Producto("Xilitol 1kg", LocalDate.now(), 15, 1);
Producto p8 = new Producto("Xilitol 1kg", LocalDate.now(), 15, 1);

// Añadir productos a la lista del super
Supermercado.getSupermercado().addProducto(p1);
Supermercado.getSupermercado().addProducto(p2);
Supermercado.getSupermercado().addProducto(p3);
Supermercado.getSupermercado().addProducto(p4);
Supermercado.getSupermercado().addProducto(p5);
Supermercado.getSupermercado().addProducto(p6);
Supermercado.getSupermercado().addProducto(p7);
Supermercado.getSupermercado().addProducto(p8);

// Printing the list
System.out.println("\nLista productos.");
Supermercado.getSupermercado().printListaProductos();

// Printing distinct items (do not repeat xilitol plz)
System.out.println("\nLista de productos sin repetir.");
Supermercado.getSupermercado().printListaProductosSinRepetir();
```

**Supermercado.java**

```
// Printing the list
public void printListaProductos() {
    listaProducto.stream()
        .forEach(p -> System.out.println("Producto " +p.getNombre() 
            + '\t' + "Precio " + p.getPrecio() + "€"
            + '\t' + "Caducidad " + p.getFechaCaducidad()));
}

// Printing distinct items (do not repeat xilitol plz)
public void printListaProductosSinRepetir() {
    listaProducto.stream()
        .distinct()
        .forEach(p -> System.out.println("Producto " +p.getNombre() 
            + '\t' + "Precio " + p.getPrecio() + "€"
            + '\t' + "Caducidad " + p.getFechaCaducidad()));
}
```

**Producto.java**

```
private String nombre;
private int seccion;
private LocalDate fechaCaducidad;
private float precio;

// constructor
public Producto(String pNombre, LocalDate pFechaCaducidad, float pPrecio, int pSeccion) {
    this.nombre = pNombre;
    this.fechaCaducidad = pFechaCaducidad;
    this.precio = pPrecio;
    this.seccion = pSeccion;
}

public LocalDate getFechaCaducidad() {
    return this.fechaCaducidad;
}

public float getPrecio() {
    return this.precio;
}

public int getSeccion() {
    return this.seccion;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}
```

### The Output

```
Lista productos.
Producto Sal 100gr  Precio 0.5€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Pimienta 25gr  Precio 0.2€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Sal 1kg    Precio 2.0€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Te limón   Precio 3.5€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Azucar 1kg Precio 2.0€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Azucar 5kg Precio 10.0€    Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Xilitol 1kg    Precio 15.0€    Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Xilitol 1kg    Precio 15.0€    Caducidad 2016-05-27

Lista de productos sin repetir.
Producto Sal 100gr  Precio 0.5€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Pimienta 25gr  Precio 0.2€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Sal 1kg    Precio 2.0€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Te limón   Precio 3.5€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Azucar 1kg Precio 2.0€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Azucar 5kg Precio 10.0€    Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Xilitol 1kg    Precio 15.0€    Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Xilitol 1kg    Precio 15.0€    Caducidad 2016-05-27
```

### The Problem

Clearly, the `.distinct()` code in `printListaProductosSinRepetir()` method is not working for me. It should display this:

```
Lista de productos sin repetir.
Producto Sal 100gr  Precio 0.5€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Pimienta 25gr  Precio 0.2€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Sal 1kg    Precio 2.0€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Te limón   Precio 3.5€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Azucar 1kg Precio 2.0€ Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Azucar 5kg Precio 10.0€    Caducidad 2016-05-27
Producto Xilitol 1kg    Precio 15.0€    Caducidad 2016-05-27
```

Without the extra `Xilitol 1kg`. The items shouldn't repeat.

### Why do I need this

I am trying to learn how `Java 8` works with the `Lambda-expressions`. So I am building myself some examples for this. The thing is that `.distinct()` is not working. I couldn't find this solution in SO. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you implemented the `equals` and `hashCode` methods within Producto.java?

Comment: No.. I just added `Producto.java` code now.

Comment: You should implement equals() and hashCode(). Otherwise distinct() is useless.

Comment: I didn't know that disctinct() only works under this conditions, I guess it's obvious now. It worked!. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/4126968 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/23699499/4126968 if you don't want/can modify the `Producto` class itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override `equals` and `hashCode` methods from `object` class in order to make this work here is an example.
Add in your `Producto.java` the following code.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((nombre == null) ? 0 : nombre.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Producto other = (Producto) obj;
    if (nombre == null) {
        if (other.nombre != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!nombre.equals(other.nombre))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Unnecessarily complicated. You get the same result using `public int hashCode() { return 31+Objects.hashCode(nombre); }` and `public boolean equals(Object obj) { return this == obj  ||  obj!=null && getClass()==obj.getClass() && Objects.equals(nombre, ((Producto)obj).nombre); }`

Comment: @Holger it worked too! Just wanted to say that the above code is the one `Eclipse` writes with `right click -> source -> Generate hashcode() and equals()...`. But I'll be using your code, since It's shorter and seems easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should override the `equal` function of the `Producto`

the `distinct()` function removes the duplicated element depending on the 
`equal()` for  the object

when you do not override the `equal()` function, the default behavior is to compare with the object reference address