# Removing duplicates from List which uses generics

Tags: java

Problem : I have a utility function which takes in a generic list to remove duplicates, Now when I use it for `List<String>` the match should case insensitive. The code uses streams (Java 8+) and i want to keep it that way.

**Note : code is in JAVA 8+**

Code :

```
public static <T> List<T> removeDuplicates(List<T> inputList) {
    List<T> result = null;
    if (inputList != null && inputList.size() > 0) {
        result = inputList.parallelStream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return result;
}
```

EG:

```
List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>();
inputList.add("a");
inputList.add("A");
inputList.add("abc");
inputList.add("ABC");
inputList.add("c");
```

When we call `removeDuplicates(inputList)` and print it

Values:

```
 a
 abc
 c
```

I don't really care if it choose `ABC` over `abc` or `A` over `a` but it should be there only once.

Is there an elegant way of solving this issue without doing an `instanceof` check ?

Comment: Why don't you just convert the `List` to a `Set`?

Comment: Why make method generic if you only handle `String`s?

Comment: @MatthewDiana it still wont solve my problem. Set remove duplicates but the don't check for case insensitive part ...

Comment: What if `T` is `Integer` - what does "case insensitive" mean then?

Comment: @Jezor this is used by multiple other objects and not just String.

Comment: @Bohemian that is the problem ... is there a way to ignore the case insensitive part if it is not a string ?

Comment: It seems like the `String` class gets treated specially compared to other objects when using your method, so using `instanceof` might be the way to go.

Comment: Try converting it to Set and convert it back to List again. Because Sets can only contain unique elements.

Comment: If you know the type of the list at compile time, just make a separate method. If you don't, there's no way to find out, thanks to type erasure.

Comment: I saw this post that might answer your question. They create a custom function that returns a predicate that is passed in to the distinct() method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property

Comment: You can use a `new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)` to filter out case-insensitive duplicates.

Comment: @shmosel as per you suggestion the only way to do this is have a separate function for String and then do the TreeSet<String> for it.

Comment: The `TreeSet` is not a requirement, just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the caller knows the type of `T` at compile time, you can have it pass an optional `Comparator<T>` to the method, and filter out duplicates using a `TreeSet`:

```
public static <T> List<T> removeDuplicates(List<T> inputList) {
    // null uses natural ordering
    return removeDuplicates(inputList, null);
}

public static <T> List<T> removeDuplicates(List<T> inputList, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    Set<T> set = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    set.addAll(inputList);
    return new ArrayList<>(set);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeDuplicates(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 2, 3)));
    System.out.println(removeDuplicates(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "B", "c"), String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extend your method to accept also a function to be applied in `map` on your stream.
This function will be generic with the same `T`, so this will solve the need for instanceof. In the String case insensitive example, the function will be `String::toLowerCase`.

```
public static <T> List<T> removeDuplicates(List<T> inputList, Function<T,T> function) {
    List<T> result = null;
    if (inputList != null && inputList.size() > 0) {
        result = inputList.parallelStream()
          .map(function)
          .distinct()
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return result;
}
```

And if you want to keep the same API for the types that don't need it, just add this overload:

```
public static <T> List<T> removeDuplicates(List<T> inputList) {
  return removeDuplicates(inputList, Function.identity());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want behavior that differs from the default equals behavior you can roll your own String:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyString {
  private final String value;

  public MyString(final String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return value;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    final MyString myString = (MyString) o;
    return StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(myString.value, value);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return value.toUpperCase().hashCode();
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    // args = {aa AA aA bb Bb cc bb CC}
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(args).map(MyString::new).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    // prints: [aa, bb, cc]
  }
}
```