# logic for removing duplicates from hashset

Tags: java, collections, hashset

Here is the scenario. I want to avoid duplicates only if 2 among the 3 fields are same value. Id will be different but if name and address both are same then that should be avoided.

I tried the following code where I add some name, id and address

```
HashSet<Employee> mySet = new HashSet<Employee>();
mySet.add(new Employee (1,"a","xxx"));
mySet.add(new Employee(2,"a", "yyy"));

for(Employee emp : mySet) {  
    System.out.println(emp.getId() + " " + emp.getName()+" "+emp.getAddress());  
}
```

I have one Employee class with setters and getters and constructor of my choice.

I wanna avoid printing if name and address (both) are gonna be repeated.

1 A xxx
2 A xxx 
The above scenario should be avoided

Can you please help me with logic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Employee` class, implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` according to your rules:

```
class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Employee(int id, String name, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, employee.name) &&
                Objects.equals(address, employee.address);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, address);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()` is certainly something you should consider.
If (for whatever reason) you only have `id` in your `equals()/hashCode()` or the other attributes are not that appropriate to check there, you may also want to consider filtering out those duplicates "manually".

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property) has already good answers to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use non default `equals` and `hashCode`. If you want, you can use e.g. guava or apache.

**GUAVA**

```
import com.google.common.base.Objects;

class Employee {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String address;

  public Employee(int id, String name, String address) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Employee employee = (Employee) o;
    return id == employee.id &&
            Objects.equal(name, employee.name) &&
            Objects.equal(address, employee.address);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(id, name, address);
  }
}
```

**APACHE**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;

class Employee {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String address;

  public Employee(int id, String name, String address) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;

    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Employee employee = (Employee) o;

    return new EqualsBuilder()
            .append(id, employee.id)
            .append(name, employee.name)
            .append(address, employee.address)
            .isEquals();
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37)
            .append(id)
            .append(name)
            .append(address)
            .toHashCode();
  }
}
```