# How to filter out the elements of the List<A> so that the List<A> only contains elements of distinct A.getId()?

Tags: java

I have a `List<A>` that contains some objects `A` with the attribute id. What I need is the list to contain only one object for an id.

```
public List<A> findAllA() {
    List<A> aList; // fetches the elements from db

    HashMap<Long, A> aMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (A a: aList) {
        aMap.put(a.getId(), a);
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(aMap.values()); 
}
```

So I put my list elements in a `HashMap`, because a `HashMap` holds distinct keys. Then a new `ArrayList<A>` with the values of the map is returned. This does work fine, but is there a more efficient way to achieve the result? Or at least a shorter one?

Comment: Your code is good. You can however make it look more **compact** by using `Stream`s, `filter` and a custom method like `distinctByKey`. Or if your elements override `equals` and `hashCode` to be different by the id, you can also just use `Stream#distinct`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)

Comment: I guess id is the primary key of A, right? When you fetch the elements from the database, why do you get multiple results for the same id anyway? I guess the most performant thing would be to modify your database query to not return multiple Entries for one id (Most likely by using DISTINCT in it).

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS: No its not the primary key. Its just an attribute of A. I didn't want to post my original code, because of the long method names like 'getSomeItFromSomePreviouslyTypedInTagSuggestion'... but I see how this can lead to misunderstandings...

Comment: So there is a possibility that two objects of A have the same id but are otherwise completly different? If yes then Is there any logic you have in mind for what A objects you would return in this case? (A random one, the newest/oldest or something like that)

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS: sadly I have to admit, that the db query returns dublicates, since a lot of joins are involved. Its written in querydsl and I didn't get the good old 'distinct' operation to run, since I'm a newby to querydsl. I figured that someone would find out, that I'm trying to cheat here :) But well I'm just fed up with querydsl for the moment. But it will remain on my todo list to optimize this atrocity of a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for less characters/lines of codes, you can use `Stream`s:

```
return aList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is assuming your `A` class overrides `equals` and two instances of `A` are equals if and only if they have the same ID.

Of course, if that's the case, you can also use a `HashSet` to eliminate the duplicates:

```
return new ArrayList<A>(new HashSet<A>(alist));
```

If your `A` class doesn't override `equals` (or `equals` doesn't behave as mentioned above) using a `HashMap` as you did is an efficient linear time solution. You can't do better in terms of average running time.

Comment: Or `LinkedHashSet` to keep the list order. Or for mutable lists: `Set<Object> tmp = new HashSet<>(); aList.removeIf(a -> !tmp.add(a.getId()));`

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 stream :

```
List<A> aList; // fetches the elements from db

Collection<A> original= aList.stream()
   .<Map<Integer, A>> collect(HashMap::new,(m,e)->m.put(e.getId(), e), Map::putAll).values();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `equals()/hashCode()` methods rely on the `id` , you could simply create a `Set` from the `List` :

```
Set<A> set = new HashSet<>(aList);
```

`Set` removes duplicate elements equals in terms of `equals()`.
If the `Set` type doesn't suit, you may still transform it into a `List` :

```
List<A> newList = new ArrayList<A>(new HashSet<A>(alist));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just going by your logic, you can try like this also

```
public List<A> findAllA() {
        List<A> aList; // fetches the elements from db

        HashMap<Long, A> aMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<Long> processedList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (A a: aList) {
            if(!processedList.contains(a.getId())) {
                processedList.add(a.getId());
                aMap.put(a.getId(), a);
            }
        }

        return new ArrayList<>(aMap.values());
    }
```