# Java 8 remove duplicate strings irrespective of case from a list

Tags: java, java-8

How can we remove duplicate elements from a list of String without considering the case for each word, for example consider below code snippet

```
    String str = "Kobe Is is The the best player In in Basketball basketball game .";
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s"));
    list.stream().distinct().forEach(s -> System.out.print(s+" "));
```

This still gives the same output as below, which is obvious

```
Kobe Is is The the best player In in Basketball basketball game .
```

I need the result as follows

```
Kobe Is The best player In Basketball game .
```

Comment: Use a TreeSet using the appropriate comparator (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER). Loop through each word, add it to the set, and if it's already there, don't print it.

Comment: Are you only looking for consecutive duplicates, or all duplicates?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Taking your question literally, to “remove duplicate strings irrespective of case from a list”, you may use

```
// just for constructing a sample list
String str = "Kobe Is is The the best player In in Basketball basketball game .";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s")));

// the actual operation
TreeSet<String> seen = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
list.removeIf(s -> !seen.add(s));

// just for debugging
System.out.println(String.join(" ", list));
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you only need to get rid of consecutive duplicates, you can use a regular expression. The regex below checks for duplicated words, ignoring case.

```
String input = "Kobe Is is The the best player In in Basketball basketball game .";
String output = input.replaceAll("(?i)\\b(\\w+)\\s+\\1\\b", "$1");

System.out.println(output);
```

Which outputs:

```
Kobe Is The best player In Basketball game .
```

Comment: When using a `java.util.regex.Pattern` one could omit the `(?i)` and write     `Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w+)\\s+\\1\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`

Comment: @Lino True, but `String.replaceAll()` doesn't accept `Pattern` parameters.

Comment: `myPattern.matcher(input).replaceAll("$1")` should work though

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fun solution to get the expected result with the use of streams.

```
String result = Pattern.compile("\\s")
                .splitAsStream(str)
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(String::toLowerCase,
                        Function.identity(),
                        (l, r) -> l,
                        LinkedHashMap::new),
                        m -> String.join(" ", m.values())));
```

prints:

```
Kobe Is The best player In Basketball game .
```

Answer (score 1):

if it's not a problem for you losing while print all the capital letters, you can do in this way

```
    list.stream()
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .distinct()
            .forEach(System.out::print)
```

Output:

> kobe is the best player in basketball game .

Comment: it seems OP doesn't want all lower case .

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your uppercase and removing lowercase:

```
String str = "Kobe Is is The the best player In in Basketball basketball game .";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s"));
for(int i = 1; i<list.size(); i++)
{
        if(list.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(i-1)))
        {
            // is lower case
            if(list.get(i).toLowerCase().equals(list.get(i)))
            {
                list.set(i,"");
            }
            else
            {
                list.set(i-1, "");
            }
        }
}

list.stream().distinct().forEach(s -> System.out.print(s+" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **one-line** solution that:

- filters out all (including non-consecutive) case-insensitive duplicates (unlike [Robby's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51552836/2032415) and [maio290's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51552867/2032415))
- preserves original case (unlike [Leviand's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51552714/2032415))

This solution makes use of the [jOOλ](https://github.com/jooq/jool) library and its [`Seq.distinct(Function<T,U>)`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.14/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html#distinct-java.util.function.Function-) method:

```
List<String> distinctWords = Seq.seq(list).distinct(String::toLowerCase).toList();
```

Result (when printed like in the question):

> Kobe Is The best player In Basketball game .

Comment: distinct by property can be achieved via this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property

Comment: Nice remark. Incidentally, that's almost exactly how it's implemented in `Seq`, the only difference being that `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` isn't used there (regular `ConcurrentHashMap` is used).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the repeating string is that those don't occur in exact same case first word is `Basketball` and other one is `basketball` so both those are not the same ones. Capital B is there in first occurance. So what you can do is you can do the comparison of string into either lower case or UPPER CASE or you can do comparison ignoring case.

Answer (score 0):

The provided solution with TreeSet is elegant. but TreeSet also sorts the elements which makes the solution inefficient.
The code below demonstrates how to implement it more efficiently using HashMap that gives precedence to the string that has more upper case letters

```
class SetWithIgnoreCase {
    private HashMap<String, String> underlyingMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(String str) {
        String lowerCaseStr = str.toLowerCase();
        underlyingMap.compute(lowerCaseStr, (k, v) -> (v == null) ? str : (compare(v, str) > 0 ? v : str));
    }

    private int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        int upperCaseCnt1 = 0;
        int upperCaseCnt2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
            upperCaseCnt1 += (Character.isUpperCase(str1.charAt(i)) ? 1 : 0);
            upperCaseCnt2 += (Character.isUpperCase(str2.charAt(i)) ? 1 : 0);
        }
        return upperCaseCnt1 - upperCaseCnt2;
    }
}
```