# filter collection of strings with values case insensitive

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

How can I filter my collection with values to be checked for equality ignoring case.

Example:
I have

```
["Value1", "vALue1", "vALue2", "valUE2"]
```

I need to have

`["Value1", "vALue2"]`

Any solutions will be good.

For example I can forbid adding new string if I already has one that equals ignoring case

or I can have collection and just filter it to get rid of strings which are equals ignoring case

Comment: if I find Value1 and VALUE1, which one should i keep????

Comment: In other words, you want the first for each group of caseinsensitive-equal values?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the first one value that I found in my collection(if there are another values which equals ignoring case)

Comment: this should solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552616/java-8-remove-duplicate-strings-irrespective-of-case-from-a-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems not to be (easily) possible with Streams alone<sup>1</sup>, but you can keep track of the already seen elements in a `Set` (O(1) lookup) and `filter` elements by whether their lowercased forms are already in that set (`Set.add` will return `false` then).

```
List<String> values = List.of("Value1", "vALue1", "vALue2", "valUE2");
Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>();
List<String> res = values.stream().filter(s -> seen.add(s.toLowerCase()))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(res);  // [Value1, vALue2]
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> E.g., `distinct` does not accept a mapping function and `Collectors.groupingBy` might does not preserve order.

Comment: why not use `seen = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);` and remove the expensive `toLowerCase()` call…

Answer (score 2):

Some Java libraries which provide `distinctBy` functionality may be used to resolve this task.

For example, `StreamEx` library ([GitHub](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex), [Maven Repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/one.util/streamex)), which stands for Extenstion of Stream API, may be used like this:

```java
import java.util.*;
import one.util.streamex.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] data = {
            "Value1", "vALue1", "vALue2", "valUE2"
        };
        List<String> noDups = StreamEx.of(data)
                .distinct(String::toLowerCase)
                .toList();
        System.out.println(noDups);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Value1, vALue2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal code example as of how this could work:

```java
String[] array = new String[] {"Value1", "vALue1", "vALue2", "valUE2"};
ArrayList<String> finalArray = new ArrayList<>();
for(String entry : array) {
    boolean alreadyContained = finalArray.stream().anyMatch(entry::equalsIgnoreCase);
    if(!alreadyContained) {
        finalArray.add(entry);
    }
}
```

Basically, you create an ArrayList of all non-duplicate entries. For each entry, check if it already is contained in the ArrayList (ignoring case), add it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

Here is a genericized example of [tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k)'s [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66102155/1762224):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ArrayUtils {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> values = List.of("Value1", "vALue1", "vALue2", "valUE2");
        List<String> deduped = dedupeCaseInsensitive(values);

        System.out.println(deduped);  // [Value1, vALue2]
    }

    /* Higher-order function */
    public static List<String> dedupeCaseInsensitive(List<String> collection) {
        return dedupeWith(collection, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    }

    public static <E> List<E> dedupeWith(List<E> list, Comparator<E> comparator) {
        Set<E> seen = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
        return list.stream().filter(s -> seen.add(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

---

### Original edit

Here is a stream version:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ArrayUtils {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] items = {"Value1", "vALue1", "vALue2", "valUE2"};
        String[] result = dedupeCaseInsensitive(items);

        // Print the resulting array.
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    public static String[] dedupeCaseInsensitive(String[] items) {
        return Arrays.stream(items)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                String::toLowerCase,
                Function.identity(),
                (o1, o2) -> o1,
                LinkedHashMap::new))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
```

---

### Original response

You can dedupe with case-insensitive logic by populating a `Map`, grabbing its values and sorting them.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayUtils {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] items = {"Value1", "vALue1", "vALue2", "valUE2"};
        String[] result = dedupeCaseInsensitive(items);

        // Print the resulting array.
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    public static String[] dedupeCaseInsensitive(String[] items) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Filter the values using a map of key being the transformation,
        // and the value being the original value.
        for (String item : items) {
            map.putIfAbsent(item.toLowerCase(), item);
        }

        List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<>(map.values());

        // Sort the filtered values by the original positions.
        Collections.sort(filtered,
                Comparator.comparingInt(str -> findIndex(items, str)));

        return collectionToArray(filtered);
    }

    /* Convenience methods */

    public static String[] collectionToArray(Collection<String> collection) {
        return collection.toArray(new String[collection.size()]);
    }

    public static int findIndex(String arr[], String t) {
        return Arrays.binarySearch(arr, t);
    }
}
```

If you use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), you do not need to sort, because the items retain their insertion order.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayUtils {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] items = {"Value1", "vALue1", "vALue2", "valUE2"};
        String[] result = dedupeCaseInsensitive(items);

        // Print the resulting array.
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    public static String[] dedupeCaseInsensitive(String[] items) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        // Filter the values using a map of key being the transformation,
        // and the value being the original value.
        for (String item : items) {
            map.putIfAbsent(item.toLowerCase(), item);
        }

        return collectionToArray(map.values());
    }

    /* Convenience methods */

    public static String[] collectionToArray(Collection<String> collection) {
        return collection.toArray(new String[collection.size()]);
    }
}}
```

Comment: You could still accept `Collection<E>` as input, making the method usable for more cases. By the way, `.filter(s -> seen.add(s))` can also be written as `.filter(seen::add)`. In fact, since the part to the left of the `::` is only evaluated once and the result captured, you can even write `.filter(new TreeSet<>(comparator)::add)` and it will do the intended thing.