# Java 8 stream with filter condition working flow

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

In a Java 8 stream with a filter condition, every element in the collection is passed to the filter for checking the condition. Here I am writing two different filter conditions and giving different workflows.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> asList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c");

    //line 1
    asList.stream().map(s -> s).filter(distinctByKey(String::toString)).forEach(System.out::println);

    Predicate<String> strPredicate = (a) -> {
        System.out.println("inside strPredicate method--");
        return a.startsWith("a");
    };

    //line 2
    asList.stream().filter(strPredicate).forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    System.out.println("inside distinctByKey method...");
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
}
```

In the above sample code, the statement *line 1* filter condition is executing only once but *line 2* is executing for every element in the collection output.

I thought the `distinctByKey` method would execute for every element in the collection, but it is not the case. Why ?

Also the `Set` object reference variable `seen` is executing only once? How is the flow working?

Comment: `distinctByKey()` runs only once because it creates a new lambda for the predicate, which then is executed on every element.

Comment: `.map(s -> s)` does literally nothing, by the way

Comment: you should also say that this code is taken *literally* from a  [Stuart Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/1059372)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`distinctByKey` is a lambda factory method. It is *returning* a `Predictate<T>`.

So when you execute: `filter(distinctByKey(String::toString))` you're in fact calling the `distinctByKey` method first, which *then* returns a `Predicate`. That predicate then gets executed for every element. Just the factory function will only be executed once.

When moving the `System.out.println` inside the returned lambda you'll get the desired print statements:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    System.out.println("inside distinctByKey method...");
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> {
        System.out.println("inside distinctByKey.lambda method... ");
        return seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That `seen` is *captured* by the lambda expression and *cached* inside the lambda, once you return the `Predicate` - the `Predicate::test` will be called multiple times with the *same instance* of `seen`

Comment: Now this answer adds to your answer, @Lino. The concept of *capturing* a local variable inside a lambda well deserves a new answer. This same technique can be applied to implement different functional programming concepts, i.e. memoization. +1

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner should we also add that it's something one *has to get used to*? It's not trivial at all understanding this when you first see it

Comment: Yes, that's so true. It's not intuitive, when I first saw this technique I also thought that my method was going to be called for every element of the stream. But once you understand the difference between *imperative* and *declarative*, you see the light.

Comment: If one understands the concept of closures, e.g. from javascript, then this may be more familiar/intuitive