# How to merge two streams in Java without duplicates according to some property?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose we have two streams as follows:

```
IntStream stream1 = Arrays.stream(new int[] {13, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9});
IntStream stream2 = Arrays.stream(new int[] {1, 2, 6, 14, 8, 10, 12});
stream1.merge(stream2); // some method which is used to merge two streams.
```

Is there any convenient way to merge these two streams without duplicates to [13, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14] by using the Java 8 stream API (the order doesn't matter). Or can we only handle one stream at the same time?

Furthermore, if the two streams are object streams, how to keep only distinct objects without overriding the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods? For example:

```
public class Student {

    private String no;

    private String name;
}

Student s1 = new Student("1", "May");
Student s2 = new Student("2", "Bob");
Student s3 = new Student("1", "Marry");

Stream<Student> stream1 = Stream.of(s1, s2);
Stream<Student> stream2 = Stream.of(s2, s3);
stream1.merge(stream2);  // should return Student{no='1', name='May'} Student{no='2', name='Bob'}
```

As long as their `no` is the same we consider them to be the same student. (so May and Marry are the same person because their numbers are both "1").

I've found the `distinct()` method, but this method is based on `Object#equals()`. If we are not allowed to overwrite the `equals()` method, how can we merge `stream1` and `stream2` to one stream which has no duplicate items?

Comment: Instead of `Arrays.stream(new int[] {13, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9});` you can write directly `IntStream.of(13, 1, etc)`.

Comment: As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52574504/1108305, `Stream.concat(stream1, stream2)` will concatenate the streams.  Excluding duplicates according to a property has its own full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23699371/1108305.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

@Jigar Joshi has answered the first part of your question which is *"how to merge two IntStream's into one"*.

Your other question of "how to merge two `Stream<T>` without overwriting the `equals()` and `hashCode()` method?" can be done using the `toMap` collector, i.e.
assuming you don't want the result as a `Stream<T>`.
Example:

```
Stream.concat(stream1, stream2)
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getNo, 
               Function.identity(), 
               (l, r) -> l, 
               LinkedHashMap::new)
      ).values();
```

if you want the result as a `Stream<T>` then one could do:

```
 Stream.concat(stream1, stream2)
       .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
               Collectors.toMap(Student::getNo,
                    Function.identity(),
                    (l, r) -> l,
                    LinkedHashMap::new), 
                    f -> f.values().stream()));
```

This is possibly not as efficient as it can be but it's another way to return a `Stream<T>` where the `T` items are all distinct but without using overriding `equals` and `hashcode` as you've mentioned.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`concat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#concat-java.util.stream.IntStream-java.util.stream.IntStream-)

```
IntStream.concat(stream1, stream2)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But it is a pity that `contact()` method does not  remove the duplicate items for us, so we have to use one more `distinct()` method.

Comment: @weaver why would you expect `concat` to remove duplicate items?

Comment: In order to remove duplicates you can call `.distinct()` after concatenation.

Comment: @weaver That's the point of streams... chain operations on the stream.

Comment: There's a full answer on removing duplicates from a stream, which could be applied to a concatenated object stream: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23699371/1108305

Answer (score 3):

for first question
you can use "flatMap"

```
    IntStream stream1 = Arrays.stream(new int[] {13, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9});
    IntStream stream2 = Arrays.stream(new int[] {1, 2, 6, 14, 8, 10, 12});

    List<Integer> result = Stream.of(stream1, stream2).flatMap(IntStream::boxed)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    //result={13, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 2, 6, 14, 8, 10, 12}
```

**EDIT**

thanks to @Vinicius for advising,
we can use

```
Stream<Integer> result = Stream.of(stream1, stream2).flatMap(IntStream::boxed).distinct();
```

here we will get a stream of all elements distinct based on the `equals` method.

Comment: Just put a distinct() after the flatMap and that is the better answer

Comment: A variant for the stream of non-primitives:
`Stream.of(stream1, stream2, ... streamN).flatMap(Function.identity())`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the [`StreamEx`](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library:

```java
Stream<Student> merged =
        StreamEx.of(stream1).append(stream2).distinct(Student::getNo)
```

This uses the StreamEx [`append`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx.html#append(java.util.stream.Stream)) method to concatenate the two streams.  It then uses the StreamEx variation of the [`distinct`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx.html#distinct(java.util.function.Function)) method which uses a function to determine whether two elements are to be considered equal:

> `public S distinct​(Function<? super T,​?> keyExtractor)`
>
> Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements of this stream (according to object equality of the results of applying the given function).