# How to find the duplicates values in a Map with in a stream of list?

Tags: java-8

Say I have this array list:

```
 List<Map<String,String>> fileDataList= new ArrayList<>();
 fileDataList.stream().forEach(t->{
  //find duplicate map values
 });
```

The list may contain duplicate values like these:

```
[
    {age:12,name:"john"}, 
    {age:11,name:"Mary"},
    {age:12,name:"john"}
]
```

Now,I would like to find the duplicate map values which match both name and age inside the stream without removing them.
I tried with HashSet, But I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holger in comments brings a point I missed. If your `Map` contains *only* of those `name` and `age` properties, you could simply do:

```
fileDataList.stream()
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

And this will be enough. If, on the other hand, you have more properties and 
what to filter by only some of them, you could use [this utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/1059372):

```
fileDataList.stream()
            .filter(distinctByKey(x -> Arrays.asList(x.get("name"), x.get("age")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you @Eugene. I think this will work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfre your list if `Map` to list of `EntrySet`.

```
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = fileDataList.stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(toList());
```