# Finding duplicated objects by two properties

Tags: java, java-8

Considering that I have a list of Person objects like this :

```
Class Person {
  String fullName;
  String occupation;
  String hobby;
  int salary;
}
```

Using java8 streams, how can I get list of duplicated objects only by fullName and occupation property?

Comment: add equals and hashCode in person class?

Comment: Have you checked out [Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23699371) ?

Comment: Well yes. I don't need to distinct duplicates, rather I need to find if they were any duplicates in fullName - occupation pair, which has to be unique. I found plenty of topics where duplicated were *removed*. I need to add them.

Answer (score 9):

By using java-8 `Stream()` and `Collectors.groupingBy()` on firstname and occupation

```
List<Person> duplicates = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getFullName() + "-" + p.getOccupation(), Collectors.toList()))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .filter(i -> i.size() > 1)
    .flatMap(j -> j.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: this is duplication of my answer IMHO

Comment: but i did not copy that, did it my self and posted at same time @oleg.cherednik

Answer (score 5):

> I need to find if they were any duplicates in fullName - occupation pair, which has to be unique

Based on this comment it seems that you don't really care about which `Person` objects were duplicated, just that there were any.

In that case you can use a stateful `anyMatch`:

```
Collection<Person> input = new ArrayList<>();

Set<List<String>> seen = new HashSet<>();
boolean hasDupes = input.stream()
                        .anyMatch(p -> !seen.add(List.of(p.fullName, p.occupation)));
```

You can use a `List` as a 'key' for a set which contains the `fullName` + `occupation` combinations that you've already seen. If this combination is seen again you immediately return `true`, otherwise you finish iterating the elements and return `false`.

Answer (score 3):

I offer solution with **O(n)** complexity. I offer to use `Map` to group given list by key (fullName + occupation) and then retrieve duplicates.

```
public static List<Person> getDuplicates(List<Person> persons, Function<Person, String> classifier) {
    Map<String, List<Person>> map = persons.stream()
                                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList())));

    return map.values().stream()
              .filter(personList -> personList.size() > 1)
              .flatMap(List::stream)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Client code:

```
List<Person> persons = Collections.emptyList();
List<Person> duplicates = getDuplicates(persons, person -> person.fullName + ':' + person.occupation);
```

Comment: Alternatively, you may combine the `filter` and `flatMap` step: `.flatMap(list -> list.size() > 1? list.stream(): null)`. But you should not force the key type to be a `String`. Creating the key for two properties via string concatenation is inefficient and error prone (might create clashes on the resulting strings).

Answer (score 1):

First implement equals and hashCode in your person class and then use.

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

Set<Person> duplicates=personList.stream().filter(p -> Collections.frequency(personList, p) ==2)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If objects are more than 2 then you use `Collections.frequency(personList, p) >1` in filter predicate.