# Select distinct fields of an ArrayList of Class X

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Class X.

```
ArrayList<X> items = new ArrayList();
```

Class X contains multiple fields, all of the type string. (id, description, brand, ...)

So what do i do if i wanna get an ArrayList of this Class which only contains distinct values for a given field?

In practice:

How can I get an ArrayList of Class X which contains all the brands but no duplicates? (get all the brands in `items` but no brand twice)

Or is there any better/more efficient way to only get a list of the brands?

\e: i dont use Java8.

Hope this isn't too confusing.

Comment: all the brands Store in `Set`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(X::getBrand))   // group your items by brand
            .values().stream()                            // stream map values
            .map(e->e.get(0))                            // for each brand get first element in brand list 
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you cann't use java8 / streams

```
    Map<String,List<X>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(X item : items){
        if(!map.containsKey(item.getBrand())){
            map.put(item.getBrand(), new ArrayList<>());
        }else{
            map.get(item.getBrand()).add(item);
        }
    }
    List<X> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String,List<X>> e : map.entrySet()){
        result.add(e.getValue().get(0));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `java.util.Set` which by definition, does not allow duplicated values.

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();
for(X x : items) {
    s.add(x.getField());
}

// "s" now contains all distinct "field"
```

there should be a version of this code using lambdas and streams. But IMO such simple code does not require it

Comment: OP wants the list to contain `X` objects, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

**1)**  Use a utility method `distinctbykey` in `filter` if you want to get unique result on some field.

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, Object> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> map.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
  }

ArrayList<X> items = new ArrayList();
items = items
  .stream()
  .filter( distinctByKey(x -> x.uniqueFiled()) ) // pass field of X object on basis of you want unique objects
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**2)** There is another way to get no duplication in list.
`Override` `equals` and `hash` function of `X` class in which you have to compare `Brand` field and then use distinct method of `stream` it will  return distinct objects list by calling of your `equals` and `hash` function.

```
ArrayList<X> items = new ArrayList();
items = items
  .stream()
  .distinct()
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**3)** If you implement `equals` and `hash` functions. then simply create a `Set` from `List`. `Set` has unique elements and ten again create `List` from that `Set`.

```
ArrayList<X> items = new ArrayList();
Set<X> set = new HashSet<X>(items); // Now set has unique elements
items = set.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()); // list have unique elemets too
```