# How to convert a List of duplicate values to a List of distinct values with respect to a field of T class

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `List<String>` which contains names I want to convert that list to an other list of unique names I found a way that works well which is:

```
public class Main {

  public Main() {
    List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

    nameList.add("Ali");
    nameList.add("Al");
    nameList.add("Ali");
    nameList.add("Al");
    nameList.add("Ai");
    nameList.add("li");
    nameList.add("li");
    nameList.add("Ai");
    System.out.print("All names are: ");
    for (String string : nameList) {
      System.out.print(string + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.print("Unique names are: ");

    for (String string : convertToUniqueList(nameList)) {
      System.out.print(string + ", ");
    }

  }

  public List<String> convertToUniqueList(List<String> listInts) {
    List<String> listDistinctInts = new ArrayList<>(listInts.size());
    for (String i : listInts) {
      if (!listDistinctInts.contains(i)) {
        listDistinctInts.add(i);
      }
    }
    return listDistinctInts;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
  }

}
```

all things are working very well and I'm getting desired results, but I want to implement the same logic as above to following scenario where I have:

```
  @Data // lombok annotation
  public class Foo {
    String name;
    int age;    
    List<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<>();    
  }

  @Data // lombok annotation
  public class Bar {
    String bloodGroup;
    String dayOfPassing;
  }
```

I want to get a list with unique day names from misc list in Main.java I tried:

```
public class Main {

  public Main() {
    Foo foo1 = new Foo();

    foo1.setName("Foo One");
    foo1.setAge(21);

    List<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<>();

    Bar bar1 = new Bar();
    bar1.setBloodGroup("O +ve");
    bar1.setDayOfPassing("Wednesday");

    Bar bar2 = new Bar();
    bar2.setBloodGroup("O +ve");
    bar2.setDayOfPassing("Wednesday");

    Bar bar3 = new Bar();
    bar3.setBloodGroup("O +ve");
    bar3.setDayOfPassing("Thursday");

    Bar bar4 = new Bar();
    bar4.setBloodGroup("O -ve");
    bar4.setDayOfPassing("Friday");

    barList.add(bar1);
    barList.add(bar2);
    barList.add(bar3);
    barList.add(bar4);

    System.out.print("All Bars with all days are: ");
    for (Bar bar : barList) {
      System.out.print(bar.dayOfPassing + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.print("Bars with Unique days are: ");
    int count = 0;
    for (Bar bar : getBarsWithUniqueDays(barList, count)) {
      System.out.print(bar.dayOfPassing + ", ");
      count++;
    }

  }

  public List<Bar> getBarsWithUniqueDays(List<Bar> barList, int count) {
    List<Bar> listDistinctBars = new ArrayList<>(barList.size());

    for (Bar bar : barList) {
      if (!listDistinctBars.get(count).getDayOfPassing().contains(bar.dayOfPassing)) {
        listDistinctBars.add(bar);
      }
      count++;
    }
    return listDistinctBars;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
  }
}
```

with that code above I'm getting Exception:

```
All Bars with all days are: Wednesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, 
Bars with Unique days are: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Main.getBarsWithUniqueDays(Main.java:124)
    at Main.<init>(Main.java:113)
    at Main.main(Main.java:133)
```

I have searched and tried a lot but in vain, any solutions to this problem...

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @YCF_L should be like `Bars with Unique days are: Wednesday, Thursday, Friday,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Map<String, Bar> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Bar ays : barList) {
        map.put(ays.dayOfPassing, ays);
    }
    barList.clear();
    barList.addAll(map.values());


    for (Bar ays : barList) {

        System.out.println("Unique names are: "+ays.dayOfPassing);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because your code is invoking `listDistinctBars.get(count)` on an empty `ArrayList` with `count` equal to `0`. However, to properly deduplicate your objects, you should look into `java.util.Set`.

Comment: I have tried that as well but unfortunately that technique requires to override `hashCode()` and when I do so ultimately I get some duplicate values....

Answer (score 0):

Best pracite is to use `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet` (when order is important) (implementation of `Set`) for unique elements.

All u need is convert your `ArrayList` to `HashSet` and after that override `equals`&`hashcode` of your class `Bar`.
Here is example of overriding [EXAMPLE](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/)

Comment: I have tried that as well but unfortunately that technique requires to override hashCode() and when I do so ultimately I get some duplicate values....

Comment: it means that u werent correct in overriding. Here is working example of overriding in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I found a way that works well which is:

I don't thing so, Instead you can just use a `Set`

```
public Set<String> convertToUniqueList(List<String> listInts) {
    return new HashSet<>(listInts);
}
```

for the second problem, you can use stream its more helpful based on the [Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property) your solution can be :

```
public List<Bar> getBarsWithUniqueDays(List<Bar> barList) {
    return barList.stream().filter(distinctByKey(Bar::getDayOfPassing))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}

public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the second part in format compatible with java 6 or 7 iff..

Comment: @ArshadAli you can use a comparator in your class for example or follow the solution posted by sasikumar