# Remove elements in a List using lambda

Tags: java, lambda

Hi I want to use lambda in java to remove duplicate elements in a list . Define if it is duplicate will be by a custom function
Let's suppose we have these objects:

```
Object1(id:1 , name:"SEVERO" , grade:"A")
Object2(id:2 , name:"SEVERO" , grade:"B")
Object3(id:3 , name:"LUCY" , grade:"A")
Object4(id:4 , name:"LUCY" , grade:"A")
Object5(id:5 , name:"PAULA" , grade:"A")
```

Expected results:

```
Object2(id:2 , name:"SEVERO" , grade:"B")
Object3(id:3 , name:"LUCY" , grade:"A")
Object5(id:5 , name:"PAULA" , grade:"A")
```

So basically if there are objects with same name, I only want to keep one of them. The one that will be kept is the one with the highest grade (order of grades: A->B->C), in case there is a tie based on the grade, any of the objects can be kept , there is not preference.

How can I do this using java lambda?

Comment: "The one that will be kept is the one with the highest grade" then probably you want to keep `Object1(id:1 , name:"SEVERO" , grade:"A")`, instead of `Object2(id:2 , name:"SEVERO" , grade:"B")`.

Comment: Also do you want to modify list or just get some data *from* it?

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with the `toMap` collector:

```
Collection<Student> result = source.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Student::getName, Function.identity(),
                        BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Student::getGrade))))
                .values();
```

- `source` is the collection we're streaming upon.
- `Student` is the objects in the source (of course this is just an
  assumption which you should change to the name of the objects in your
  collection).
- `Student::getName` is the keyMapper used to extract the keys for the
  map.
- `Function.identity()` is the valueMapper used to extract the values
  for the map.
- `BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Student::getGrade))` is
  the merge function used to resolve conflicts in the case two given
  objects have the same name.
- `values` yields the values of the map as we no longer care about the
  keys.

if you want exactly a `List<T>` instead of a `Collection<T>` then feel free to pass the result of the above pipeline into the `ArrayList<>(...)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at this question, which is more generic and has a lot of good answers:

[Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)