# Filter list by properties of a field of the list object

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

Given all `TypeA` instances in a `List<TypeA>` have an instance of `SubTypeB` set in the superTypeB field, I need to filter out duplicate `TypeA` instances from the list, where a duplicate means the values of `propertyA` and `propertyB` from the `SubTypeB` both match. Is there a way to do this with the Java 8 stream API?

```
public class TypeA {
  private SuperTypeB superTypeB;
  public SuperTypeB getSuperTypeB(){ return superTypeB; }
}

public class SuperTypeB {
  private String propertyX;
}

public class SubTypeB extends SuperTypeB {
  private String propertyA;
  private String propertyB;
  public String getPropertyA(){ return propertyA; }
  public String getPropertyB(){ return propertyB; }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)

Comment: Not entirely. I found a custom `distinctByKeys` filter predicate function [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/stream-distinct-by-multiple-fields/) that can filter duplicates as I've defined them above (```propertyA``` and ```propertyB``` of ```SubTypeB``` match), from a list of ```SubTypeB```. My problem is returning a filtered list of ```TypeA``` using that predicate function on TypeA's ```superTypeB``` property.

Comment: @skidalgo, So just to be clear, lets say you have three items in the list, A,B,C. A and B are duplicates, which C is distinct. What should your algorithm return?

Comment: You still have a `Stream<TypeA>` after the `filter` so you simply have to `collect` it into a `List<TypeA>`.

Comment: @RajanPrasad it should return the first occurrence of each distinct object in the original list.

Comment: @Shaw my problem is I don’t know how to write an expression that filters a list based on a set of properties in a subtype instance of the supertype field of the list object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sure to not `map` before you `filter` to collect to the same type. Using a [`distinctByKey` utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/1746118), you can further choose to `collect` to a `List` as :

```
List<TypeA> filteredTypeAs = typeAList.stream()
        .filter(distinctByKey(s -> {
            SubTypeB subTypeB = (SubTypeB) s.getSuperTypeB();
            return Arrays.asList(subTypeB.getPropertyA(), subTypeB.getPropertyB());
        }))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

***Note***: This relies on the assumption as stated in the question that all the subtypes are possible to cast without an `instanceof` check.

Comment: There are two problems here.
1. If for a TypeA instance, the member superTypeB is not of SubTypeB class, this will throw a ClassCastException,
2. You will need to provide the equals override method in SubTypeB class here as well.

See if my answer seems fine to you.

Comment: @RajanPrasad for (1), the answer relies on what the question stated, for (2) there is an easier way to deal with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to `override` `equals` and `hashCode` method for the types `TypeA` and `SubTypeB`?

If yes, this is fairly straightforward. If no, I will edit this answer accordingly.

```
class TypeA {
    private SuperTypeB superTypeB;
    public SuperTypeB getSuperTypeB(){ return superTypeB; }


        @Override
        public boolean equals( final Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof TypeA)) return false;
            TypeA typeA = (TypeA) o;
            return superTypeB.equals(typeA.superTypeB);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(superTypeB);
        }
    }

    class SubTypeB extends SuperTypeB {
        private String propertyA;
        private String propertyB;
        public String getPropertyA(){ return propertyA; }
        public String getPropertyB(){ return propertyB; }


        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof SubTypeB)) return false;
            SubTypeB subTypeB = (SubTypeB) o;
            return propertyA.equals(subTypeB.propertyA) &&
                propertyB.equals(subTypeB.propertyB);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(propertyA, propertyB);
        }

    }
```

After this, all you need to do is this:

`List<TypeA> finalList = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());`

The only assurance that you can get in the stream API that you will get the first occurrence of each distinct object is through the order in which the stream emits objects. Otherwise, you have no control over which element you encounter first.

Comment: binding `TypeA` to a specific `equals` and `hashcode` might not be extensible(what if another attribute is to be added to this class) and changing this to further use `distinctByKey` would make much sense fo the same reason.

Comment: To the OP - it is important to override hashCode() also when you override equals(), especially if a class needs to be used by distinct. See this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60767490/java-stream-distinct-does-not-work-on-custom-objects.

Comment: This would probably be a better solution if I owned the class I'm trying to filter a list of. In this case, I don't.

Comment: @skidalgo I understand. That is what I wanted to clarify in my first line of the answer.