# Filtering unique words without changing case in java 8

Tags: java, java-stream, distinct, case-insensitive

I want to filter the list by unique elements with case insensitive filtering using java 8.

E.g:
1) Input: Goodbye bye Bye world world WorlD

Output: Goodbye bye world

2) Input: Sam went went to to To his business

Output: Sam went to his business

I tried by following code. I have used distinct() for unique elements and map(x->x.toLowerCase()) so that distinct() will filter unique elements by lowering its case.

```
    System.out.println("Enter the no of lines u will input:: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer noOfLines = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    List<String> listForInput;
    List<List<String>> allInputs = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0; i<noOfLines; i++)
    {
        String receivedLine = sc.nextLine();

        String[] splittedInput = receivedLine.split(" ");

        List<String> list =  Stream.of(splittedInput)
                .map(x->x.toLowerCase())
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        list.forEach(x-> System.out.print(x+" "));
```

but in the output I get all the elements in lower case. Is there better I can do using java 8 or m I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below solution with `Java-8`

```
System.out.println("Enter the no of lines u will input:: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer noOfLines = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        List<List<String>> allInputs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfLines; i++) {
            String receivedLine = sc.nextLine();

            List<String> list = Stream.of(Pattern.compile("\\s").splitAsStream(receivedLine)
                    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.toMap(String::toLowerCase, Function.identity(), (l, r) -> l, LinkedHashMap::new),
                            m -> String.join(" ", m.values())))
                    .split(" ")).collect(Collectors.toList());

            list.forEach(x -> System.out.print(x + " "));

        }
```

Comment: Splitting the string, joining it, and then splitting it again? That looks unnecessary to me. If you replace `m -> String.join(" ", m.values())` with `m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())`, you can remove the `Stream.of(` and the `.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: Yes, @MC Emperor you are correct, we can modify this code as per our requirements

Answer (score 2):

You are transforming all to lowercase using `.map(x->x.toLowerCase())`.

You can use a `TreeSet` to maintain unique and `removeIf` for removing from list

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(splittedInput));
TreeSet<String> unique = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
list.removeIf(e -> !unique.add(e)); // Check if already have then remove
```

Comment: Have you tested your code? This code throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`, because `Arrays.asList` returns a list backed by the underlying array, so its size cannot be changed. (Use `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...))` in order to fix it.) By the way, the output is different of OP's expected output, as in that the words are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @MCEmperor Thanks for pointing out. `list` won't be sorted here, it will be the same order as OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it. While the usecase is slightly different, this proposed solution is the same as [this answer by Stuart Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property/27872852#27872852).

In essence, you want to apply a *stateful filter*: you want to discard certain elements based on elements already seen before. This is more or less what `distinct()` does, however, `distinct()` is restricted to the `equals` method. The following method provides a `Predicate` which maintains state:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
}
```

The desired can then be achieved using the following:

```
Arrays.stream(receivedLine.split(" "))
    .filter(distinctByKey(String::toLowerCase))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **LinkedHashSet** like below,

```
for(int i =0; i<noOfLines; i++)
        {
            String receivedLine = sc.nextLine();

            String[] splittedInput = receivedLine.toLowerCase().split(" ");

            Set<String> list =  new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(splittedInput));

            list.forEach(x-> System.out.print(x+" "));
         }
```