# How to replace for loop with stream in java 8

Tags: java, for-loop, object, java-8, java-stream

I am using the below method and need to use stream and lamdas in java 8.

```
public static void addMemberships(final int key, MembershipData[] members) throws SpiderException
  {
    HashMap<String, MembershipData> duplicates = new HashMap<>();
    for(MembershipData m: members) {
      duplicates.putIfAbsent(m.subjectOfCare, m);
    }
    members = duplicates.values().toArray(new MembershipData[0]);
    internalMembershipToolkit.verifyData(key, members);
}
```

I tried using **members.forEach(duplicates.putIfAbsent(m.subjectOfCare, m));** but it didnt work.
How can I replace the for loop with stream?

Comment: `members` is an array, you would have to use `Arrays.stream(members)`... Why do you need a stream?

Comment: yes it is fine. I need to get rid of the forloop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `putIfAbsent`. You can stream over the elements of the array and collect them to a `Map`, using a merge function to get rid of duplicates.

```
Map<String, MembershipData> duplicates = 
    Arrays.stream(members)
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.subjectOfCare,
                                    Function.identity(),
                                    (m1,m2)->m1));
```

Or, to include the conversion to array in the same statement:

```
members = 
    Arrays.stream(members)
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.subjectOfCare,
                                    Function.identity(),
                                    (m1,m2)->m1))
          .values()
          .toArray(new MembershipData[0]);
```

Comment: It works. Can you explain what m1 and m2 represents here?

Comment: @ShaviPathirana they represent two values of the Map (`MembershipData` instances) having the same key. (m1,m2)->m1 means that in case of two values having the same key, the first value will be kept in the Map and the second value will be discarded.

Comment: how about a `distinctByKey` approach for the values collected before the array conversion?

Comment: @Naman Where is `distinctByKey` defined (and in which Java version)? I'm not familiar with that method.

Comment: @Eran It's not an inbuilt capability of the JDK, but here is a [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property) illustrating it.