# find duplicate entries with streams in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I got the following Problem:

I have to iterate over a `List` with students and compare their ids to find duplicates. After finding these duplicates I have to write them in a String. Sounds pretty simple so far.

```
students.stream()
    .filter(i-> Collections.frequency(students, i) >1)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But when I try the code above, I don't get any duplicates printed out. I know that it isn't working because I'm not comparing the student ids, but I don't know how to compare them.

My output is blank right now.

Student looks like this:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    // All-args constructor, getters and setters
    // omitted for brevity
}
```

And this is the my example List:

```
public static ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    new Student("Willi", 373583),
    new Student("Anselma", 476749),
    new Student("Noll", 345909),
    new Student("Inessa", 307055),
    new Student("Godart", 423496),
    new Student("Sissie", 393508),
    new Student("Allin", 434824),
    new Student("Catharine", 374286),
    new Student("Kore", 319004),
    new Student("Cornell", 325856),
    new Student("Mikkel", 468023),
    new Student("Ross", 383096),
    new Student("Robbie", 434105),
    new Student("Cariotta", 451072),
    new Student("Wendye", 334066),
    new Student("Janey", 494932),
    new Student("Nonna", 303659),
    new Student("Franklin", 460296),
    new Student("Kikelia", 466208),
    new Student("Jade", 497277),
    new Student("Traver", 451487),
    new Student("Alain", 304500),
    new Student("Jude", 335189),
    new Student("Gaile", 396638),
    new Student("Hilarius", 352284),
    new Student("Bengt", 463248),
    new Student("Brok", 473778),
    new Student("Keri", 345246),
    new Student("Ingar", 488058),
    new Student("Almeta", 422016),
    new Student("Hanny", 460693),
    new Student("Mattias", 337679),
    new Student("Cristabel", 356625),
    new Student("Banky", 320692),
    new Student("Karolina", 487674),
    new Student("Osmond", 397483),
    new Student("Essy", 384638),
    new Student("Katha", 320650),
    new Student("Dorey", 476369),
    new Student("Harlan", 499766),
    new Student("Jess", 416688),
    new Student("Bevon", 338526),
    new Student("Phaidra", 367390),
    new Student("Arthur", 341507),
    new Student("Krista", 318817),
    new Student("Riki", 470347)));
```

Comment: add a `map` before filter that gets the id from Student and then use that id in filter (and frequency)

Comment: Override Student `equals()` method to compare ids or add `.map(Student::id)` before filter

Comment: i added .map(Student::id) but im not sure what to write into the filter, thank you for your help

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post the definition of your `Student` class? Also can you post a sample `Student` list and the output you want to get from that sample list?

Comment: The only thing you didn't add is the output you want to get after processing your sample list.

Answer (score 2):

For each element you have to traverse `students` to check the frequency. A bit more optimized version would be to group it once and print the ones, that are duplicated:

```
students.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Ok So I tried that, but it still didn´t print out anything. after I set the filter value to 0 it prints out some references.  of the students objects but not the IDs

Comment: @Pody you need to override `equals` and `hashCode`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm pretty new to Java and Lamdas but could you show me in which way I have to override equals and hashCode?

Comment: @Pody you don't have to do that manually, your ide will take care of that. Foe example if you're using intellij, here's how to do that (section "euqals and hashCode"): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html

Comment: @Pody `Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getId, ...` would be an appropriate usage for printing just the ids for those which have multiple occurrences in this existing code.

Comment: @Pody This is a good approach, but replace `Function.identity()` with `Student::getId` as Naman suggests.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions would be to implement a stateful Predicate:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(
    Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {

    Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); 
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null; 
}
```

And to get a new filtered collection by Id, you can use:

```
List<Student> studentListFiltered = studentList.stream() 
  .filter(distinctByKey(s -> s.getId())) 
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Worth linking some source - [Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property). But this collects distinct `Student` and not print the ids for those which are duplicates as in the question.