# Java merging 2 sets while comparing and keeping objects based on specific fields

Tags: java, java-8, set, java-stream

```
class Object {
  string name;
  Time date;
  string createdBy;
  int version;
}
```

How do I merge two sets of Objects, with the requirement that if an object from Set1 has matching `name` and `version` as an object from Set2, keep only the one from Set2 in the resulting merged set.

E.g.

Set1: `{ Object1(name:wilson, date:00:00:00, createdBy:admin, version:1), Object2(name:wilson, date:00:00:00, createdBy:admin, version:2) }`

Set2: `{ Object3(name:arizona, date:00:00:00, createdBy:user, version:5), Object4(name:wilson, date:00:00:00, createdBy:user, version:1) }`

With the resulting merged set:
`{ Object4(name:wilson, date:00:00:00, createdBy:user, version:1), Object2(name:wilson, date:00:00:00, createdBy:admin, version:2), Object3(name:arizona, date:00:00:00, createdBy:user, version:5), }` (ordering doesn't matter)

I can union the two sets and but I'm not sure how to take advantage of Java 8 streams to add this filtering condition

Comment: merge and then find [`distinctByKey`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property).

Answer (score 0):

If you consider your objects to be equal if the name and version is the same then you could define that as your equality test (i.e. override `equals` and `hashcode` in your class).

If you have defined that condition as equals then it's a simple matter of storing the collections in a set:

```
Set<Object> mergedSet = new HashSet(set2);
mergedSet.addAll(set1);
```

Notice I added set2 first so that the objects there take precedence.

If this is a special condition and not generally representative of equal objects, then:

```
Set<Object> mergedSet = new HashSet(set2);
set1.stream()
    .filter(o1 -> set2.stream()
        .noneMatch(o2 -> o1.name.equals(o2.name) && o1.version == o2.version))
    .forEach(mergedSet::add);
```