# Map collect distinct values on condition

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to collect a list into a map but I have duplicate entry in the list object.

So suppose I have `aList` where in that I have

> [{1, "abc.jpg"}, {2, "bcd.png"}, {1, "mno.jpg"}, {3, "abc.jpg"}, {1, null}, {1, ""}]

Now in above list you can see 1 has value at repetition with different values.

I want to collect the above list into map provided only if it has some value in it.

like in above set you may have question if I find distinct then collect by grouping them which filled value will be picked my answer is any filled value is required but not empty, whitespace or null.

so anyone could be okay except in three case **empty, whitespace or null**.

I just want to set in my list if that id has any image or not therefore checking for only empty, whitespace or null.

**Output(Ambiguous):**

Output 1

> [{1, "abc.jpg"}, {2, "bcd.png"}, {3, "abc.jpg"}]

Output 2

> [{2, "bcd.png"}, {1, "mno.jpg"}, {3, "abc.jpg"}]

**Both above list result could be the output in map.**

**My Approach:**

```
    itemImageMap = imageService.findByItemUuidIn(itemUuids)
   .stream().filter(obj->(Objects.nonNull(obj)&& Objects.nonNull(obj[1])))
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(obj->String.valueOf(obj[0]), obj->String.valueOf(obj[1])));
```

I am getting duplicate key error.

For more clarity on what my purpose is to collect this in map.
Once I collect into map my goal is this =>

```
itemDetailsList.stream().filter(obj->itemImageMap.containsKey(obj.getItemUuid())).map(obj-> {
            
                String imageUrl = itemImageMap.get(obj.getItemUuid());
                
                if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(imageUrl))
                    obj.setShowImage(true);
                
                return obj;
            });
```

if I have a path then set true else default is false.

Comment: It would be so much easier to help you if instead of the long read you just provided an input (as you did) and an expected output.

Comment: @MaksymRudenko added expected result since output is ambiguous therefore both possible result presented

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the duplicate key error use the overloaded version of `toMap` with a third parameter indicating which value to keep in case of a duplicate. For example to keep the first value:

```
 .collect(Collectors.toMap(obj->String.valueOf(obj[0]), obj->String.valueOf(obj[1]), (first, second) -> first));
```

But in case of duplicates, instead of ignoring a value, you can also use your keys to group the values into a list to get a `Map<String,List<String>` instead of `Map<String,String>`. Something like:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(obj->String.valueOf(obj[0]), 
                                   Collectors.mapping(obj->String.valueOf(obj[1]), 
                                   Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = List.<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>of(
    new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(1, "abc.jpg"),
    new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(2, "bcd.png"),
    new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(1, "mno.jpg"),
    new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(3, "abc.jpg"),
    new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(1, null),
    new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(1, "")
);

var map = list.stream()
    .filter(it -> it.getValue() != null && !it.getValue().isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v1));

System.out.println(map);
```

> {1=abc.jpg, 2=bcd.png, 3=abc.jpg}

I used Java 11 `var` and `List.of`, but the code could easily be adapted to Java 8. Java is so dang verbose, `new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(1, "abc.jpg")` gives me headache every time I want to create a pair.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collectors.groupingBy` using the `getItemUuid()` method with subsequent downstreams:

- `Collectors.mapping` to get the image URL (I assume there is a method `MyObject#getUrl`).
- `Collectors.filtering` to filter out the invalid Strings as of [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) and later, otherwise you need to use `filter` before you enter the `collect` method.

**Java 8**

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = list.stream()
    .filter(obj -> obj.getUrl() != null && !obj.getUrl().trim().isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            MyObject::getItemUuid,
            Collectors.mapping(MyObject::getUrl, Collectors.toList())));
```

**Java 9+**

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getItemUuid,
            Collectors.mapping(MyObject::getUrl,
                    Collectors.filtering(url -> url != null && !url.trim().isEmpty(), 
                            Collectors.toList()))));
```

Result:

> `{1=[abc.jpg, mno.jpg], 2=[bcd.png], 3=[abc.jpg]}`

Comment: I don't have Collectors.filtering I am using java 8

Comment: Ah, my mistake. If you wait, I will include a Java 8 way in few hours :)

Comment: ok. I am waiting

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: ok so the thing is I want to collect in `Map<String, String>` where `Map<itemUuid, imageUrl>` if you see my output...also I said with single key it should have only 1 value not multiple but you have clubbed those values....@abhijeet sarkar seems to have done it very nicely if you look at his answer

Comment: How to decide if it would be `abc.jpg` or `mno.jpg`?

Comment: I don't need it na just to put boolean if there is an image else false so that when user clicks on this icon it will open a modal which will call my imageService api that will bring all images referenced to this itemUuid actually I don't want to show modal if there are no images

Answer (score 0):

If I got your idea correctly - here is my answer inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property):

```
class Data {
Integer id;
String name;

public Data(Integer id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Data{" + "id=" + id + ", name='" + name + '\'' + '}';
}
}

public class Main {

public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Data> list = List.of(new Data(1, "abc.jpg"), new Data(2, "bcd.png"), new Data(1, null));

    List<Data> result = list.stream()
                            .filter(d -> d.name != null && !d.name.equals(""))
                            .filter(distinctByKey(Data::getId))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

}

Comment: will it work if I have duplicate in first case filter but it might give exception in second case maybe when It couldn't determine distinct key.....can you run with adding one more {1, "mno.jpg"}

Comment: The JDK has a class for what you call `Data` - `Map.Entry`.

Comment: @Kramer I tried with `        List<Data> list = List.of(new Data(1, "abc.jpg"), new Data(2, "bcd.png"), new Data(1, null), new Data(1, "mno.jpg"), new Data(1, "mno.jpg"));
` and it worked. Key is the "1", not the image `name`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar You don't have to use that class if you don't want to. The part that solves your problem is the `Predicate`.

Comment: I don't have a problem, OP does.