# Need to eliminate the duplicate schema from two different list<shema>

Tags: java, spring

Lets consider I have two lists

### List1:

```
[{
“problem”: “prb1",
“status”: “ACTIVE”,
“createTs”: “somedate-1"
}]
```

### List 2:

```
[{
“problem”: “prb1",
“status”: “ACTIVE”,
“date”: “somedate-1"
},
{
“problem”: “prb1",
“status”: “ACTIVE”,
“date”: “somedate-2"
}]
```

I want to see if there is an ACTIVE problem in the list2 that doesn't exist as ACTIVE in the list1.

I tried below which is not covering duplicate entry(above scenario)

```java
   list2.removeAll(list1);
             activeprob =
            list2
            .stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(list -> list.getStatus().equals("ACTIVE"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In other way I want to eliminate the duplicate entry in list2 comparing with list1 based on status and date.
having same problem is not a concern but should be unique in terms of date.

Please share your insights

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property

Comment: Hi Surendra, Maybe you need to provide a custom `equals()` method for your schema class.  By default, the equals() method looks to see if the objects are the same memory address.  But I think you want your equals() method to compare the three fields in one schema object to each schema other.  Good luck!

Comment: @devdanke 
Thanks for your response !!
Can you please elaborate with some code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this, this is going to remove if the active record in list2 is not not active in list1 and same problem name and date. I hope it helps.

```
list2.removeIf(obj -> {
        List filteredList1 = list1.stream()
                .filter(ob -> obj.getProblem().equals(ob.getProblem())
                        && (!"ACTIVE".equals(ob.getStatus()) && "ACTIVE".equals(obj.getStatus()) )
                        && ob.getDate().equals(obj.getDate()) )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return filteredList1.isEmpty();
    } );
```

IGNORE from here: 
I hope you have almost done, except the small change. I am adding a condition to the filter.

```
activeprob = list2 .stream() .filter(Objects::nonNull) .filter(list -> list.getStatus().equals("ACTIVE") && notActivelyAvailable(list, list1)) .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

create a method like this or else you can have this filtered list readily available and can use it directly instead of calling `notActivelyAvailable` method.

```
public boolean notActivelyAvailable(YourClass obj, List<YourClass> list1) {
   List<YourClass> filteredList1 = list.stream().filter(yourObj -> "Active".equals(yourObj.getStatus()).collect(Collectors.toList());
if ( filteredList1.contains(obj)) return false;
else return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your resonse!!
Basically in my scenario need to do couple of things:
1) eliminate the entry in "list2" which is matching with "list1" 
2)out of filtered list need to filter for list2.getstatus is "ACTIVE"

for first step i did as below:
list2.removeAll(list1)   
then applied stream and filter to pick active problem

list2.removeAll(list1)    --> I think thisis some how not working for all scenarios

Comment: have you tried executing the code as I suggested and didn't work?

Comment: tried that , i could able to make that happen !!

Can you please guide me how to filter the duplicate entries from two lists 

LIST 1:
----------
[{ “problem”: “prb1", “status”: “ACTIVE”, “createTs”: “somedate-1" }]

LIST2:
---------
[{ “problem”: “prb1", “status”: “ACTIVE”, “date”: “somedate-1" },

 { “problem”: “prb1", “status”: “ACTIVE”, “date”: “somedate-2" }]

Filterdlist should have below entry
filteredlist :
--------------
{ “problem”: “prb1", “status”: “ACTIVE”, “date”: “somedate-2" }]

Comment: list2.retainAll(list1) can get you all duplicated objects only..

Comment: I need the same  in other way , need to exclude  those duplicate entries and have distinct entries in list 2

Comment: list2.removeAll(list1); used this one , but its not covering all scenarios

Comment: what is your date format are you considering the time as well?

Comment: I think we missed that date part actually, which list is latest list 1 or list 2

Comment: Giving details for more clarification:

List1:
-------

{
            "problem": "NOSTOCK",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "UserId": "surendra",
           "date": "2021-03-29T10:02:38.496354200Z"
        }

Comment: list2:
------

{
            "problem": "NOSTOCK",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "UserId": "surendra",
           "date": "2021-03-29T10:02:38.496354200Z"
        },
  
{
            "problem": "OUT_OF_STOCK",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "UserId": "surendra",
           "date": "2021-03-30T10:02:38.496354200Z"
        }

Comment: onsider this is the scenario 

list1 has old details and list 2 has old and new details.
I need to filter out only new details from list2.
from above scenario i need to extract only below:
filterList:
------------
{
            "problem": "OUT_OF_STOCK",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "UserId": "surendra",
           "date": "2021-03-30T10:02:38.496354200Z"
        }

Comment: list2.removeIf(obj -> {
            List filteredList1 = list1.stream()
                    .filter(ob -> obj.getProblem().equals(ob.getProblem())
                            && (!"ACTIVE".equals(ob.getStatus()) && "ACTIVE".equals(obj.getStatus()) )
                            && ob.getDate().equals(obj.getDate()) )
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return filteredList1.isEmpty();
        } );

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest doing is

1. Define  hashCode and equals methods for the Problem class (most IDEs can auto generate these methods) if you only want to use the date for equality do that
2. Convert the List to a Set for improved efficiency, and use the HashSet.contains method
3. Use a for loop to iterate over the Set. This will allow you to debug the code easier as it is more verbose and you can put a breakpoint in the for loop to see more clearly each step

An example for loop could be

```
for(Problem p:list2){
   if(list1.contains(p)&&p.status==ACTIVE){
       list2.remove(p);
   }
}
```

Then list2 should have all duplicates that are ACTIVE removed

Comment: @rushkin Janowski
Thanks for your response!!
Consider this is the scenario 

list1 has old details and list 2 has old and new details.
I need to filter out only new details from list2.
from above scenario i need to extract only below:

List2:
-------
{
“problem”: “prb1",
“status”: “ACTIVE”,
“date”: “somedate-2"
}]

Comment: Have you tried using the for loop and stepping through each step using your debugger as I suggested? You can definitely achieve what you want using the for loop as I explained in my answer