# Remove duplicates from list based on some property

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to remove duplicate objects from a list based on some properties and have distinct values.

```
List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I need to remove the objects having same id and value and having status 'COMPLETE'. I need distinct values of this combination: id, value and status = COMPLETE
My code is like this:

```
private static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKeys(Function<? super T, ?>... keyExtractors) {
    final Map<List<?>, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
 
return t -> 
{
  final List<?> keys = Arrays.stream(keyExtractors)
              .map(ke -> ke.apply(t))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
   
  return seen.putIfAbsent(keys, Boolean.TRUE) == null;
};
}
```

But I need to filter based on three conditions: same id, value and status = 'COMPLETE'.
Example:

```
Order object1: id=1, value="test", status =COMPLETE
Order object2: id=2, value="abc", status =INCOMPLETE
Order object3: id=1, value="test", status =COMPLETE
Order object4: id=1, value="test", status =COMPLETE

Output:
Order object1: id=1, value="test", status =COMPLETE
Order object2: id=2, value="abc", status =INCOMPLETE
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: why didn't you just add a .filter(e -> ...) on your Stream?

Comment: I need to filter based on three conditions: same id, value and status = 'COMPLETE'

Comment: Use a map as intermediate store and your property combinations as the key.

Comment: @KrishnanunniPV so?

Comment: @Stultuske I'm able to find distinct values using above method. But how to add status =Complete also in that filter?

Comment: @Thomas the above method does the same. But how to include status = COMPLETE in that?

Comment: you are aware you can have several conditions in a single conditional statement?

Comment: Well if only status COMPLETE should be equal just check for that and map anything else to a synthetic "unique" element.

Comment: @Thomas I need distinct values of this combination: id, value and status = COMPLETE

Comment: And how do you want to handle those with status != Complete?

Comment: @Thomas no need to do anything with status != Complete

Comment: Then first use `.filter()` to only keep those with status == COMPLETE.

Comment: This will filter out other status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231054/discussion-between-krishnanunni-p-v-and-thomas).

Comment: Well, you should be clear then. So `status != COMPLETE` should be unique in any case even with the same id and value? That's where "map to a synthetic unique status" comes in (you could use `Object` and either store `status` if it is complete or `new Object()` in other cases).

Comment: @Thomas can you give some code snippet

Answer (score 1):

To remove items with `COMPLETE` status use [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method. To remove duplicates use [distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) method.
In order to use `distinct` your object needs to implement `equals` method. Following is the demo code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<DataObject> list = List.of(new DataObject(1,"abc","processing"),
                        new DataObject(2,"bcd","complete"),
                        new DataObject(1,"abc","processing"),
                        new DataObject(3,"abf","processing"));
        
        List<DataObject> result = list.stream()
                        .filter(d-> !d.getStatus().equals("complete"))
                        .distinct()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    
}

class DataObject {
    private int id;
    private String data;
    private String status;
    
    public DataObject(int id, String data, String status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
        this.status = status;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((data == null) ? 0 : data.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }

    //this is eclipse autogenerated code
   //modify conditions as you want
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        DataObject other = (DataObject) obj;
        if (data == null) {
            if (other.data != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!data.equals(other.data))
            return false;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id: " + id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
    
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
[id: 1, id: 3]
```

If you don't want to implement `equals` then you can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/15273968) after `filter` operation.

Edit: updating the solution as question has changed.
Create a wrapper object which will have equals method based on your needs:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<DataObject> list = List.of(new DataObject(1,"abc","complete"),
                        new DataObject(2,"bcd","complete"),
                        new DataObject(1,"abc","complete"),
                        new DataObject(3,"aaa","complete"));
        
        List<DataObject> result = list.stream()
                        .map(Wrapper::new)
                        .distinct()
                        .map(Wrapper::getContent)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    
}

class Wrapper {
    DataObject dto;
    public Wrapper(DataObject dto) {
        this.dto = dto;
    }
    
    public DataObject getContent() {
        return this.dto;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //return this.dto.hashCode();
        //considering id is unique and you haven't implemented hashCode
        return this.dto.getId();
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //Todo: improve the implementation as per your needs
        
        Wrapper w = (Wrapper) obj;
        DataObject other = w.getContent(); 
        
        if (!this.dto.getData().equals(other.getData()))
            return false;
        if (this.dto.getId() != other.getId())
            return false;
        if (this.dto.getStatus() != other.getStatus())
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}

class DataObject {
    private int id;
    private String data;
    private String status;
    
    public DataObject(int id, String data, String status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
        this.status = status;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id: " + id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
    
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
[id: 1, id: 2, id: 3]
```

Comment: I don't want to filter out complete status. Please see my edit in question

Comment: Then from my answer, remove `filter` clause and in class's `equals` method compare `status` as well. Alternatively you can create a wrapper object which will check this, I'll update the answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

There is unfortunately no built-in method to distinct a collection based on criteria. You need to **group** the list in two nested maps to find out the duplicated objects. It's structure can be one of these:

- `Map<Integer, Map<String, List<Order>>` where `Integer` is the `id` and `String` is the `value`.
- `Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Order>>` where `Integer` is the `id` and `String` is the `value`.

Once grouped, you easily detect the same objects by your criteria because each list will contain two or more of such objects. All you need is `filter` and `flatMap` to get the duplicated objects into `List<Order>`.

1. Grouping

   ```
   Map<Integer, Map<String, List<Order>>> maps = orderList.stream()
            .filter(order -> order.getState() == State.COMPLETED)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Order::getId,
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getValue)));
   ```
2. Extraction

   ```
   List<Order> duplicates = maps.entrySet().stream()
           .flatMap(map -> map.getValue().entrySet().stream()
               .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size() > 1)
               .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```
3. Remove the duplicates from the original list.

   ```
   orderList.removeAll(duplicates);
   ```

**Edit:** I have noticed the question was edited and the problem is slightly different. If you want to *keep* one of the duplicated items, we only need to change the second step a little bit. The third step will not be needed since we can directly extract the first item of the each grouped list:

2. Extraction (final step)

   ```
   List<Order> nonDuplicates = maps.entrySet().stream()
          .flatMap(map -> map.getValue().values().stream()
              .map(orders -> orders.get(0)))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

Comment: this will remove all the duplicates. I need to keep one record of it

Comment: I am sorry for the late reaction. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use TreeSet to remove duplicated objects

```java
class TestClass
{
    String value1;
    int value2;
    String value3;
}

// here we consider the objects with same value1 and value2 are equal to each other
TreeSet<TestClass> set = new TreeSet<>( (obj1,obj2)->
        Objects.equals(obj1.value1,obj2.value1) && obj1.value2 == obj2.value2 ? 0 :
                obj1.value3.compareTo(obj2.value3)
);

TestClass tc1 = new TestClass();
tc1.value1 = "1";
tc1.value2 = 1;
tc1.value3 = "tc1";
// tc2 has the same value1 and value2 with tc1
TestClass tc2 = new TestClass();
tc2.value1 = "1";
tc2.value2 = 1;
tc2.value3 = "tc2";
TestClass tc3 = new TestClass();
tc3.value1 = "2";
tc3.value2 = 1;
tc3.value3 = "tc3";

set.add(tc1);
set.add(tc2);
set.add(tc3);

for(TestClass tc : set)
{
    System.out.printf("v1 : %s, v2: %s, v3: %s \n",tc.value1,tc.value2,tc.value3);
}
```

output shows `tc2` are not added to TreeSet

```
v1 : 1, v2: 1, v3: tc1 
v1 : 2, v2: 1, v3: tc3
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to group the objects based on keys (requires *correct* implementation of **equals and hashCode** methods for Order):

```java
var t = Arrays.asList(new Order("1", "AA", "Not Completed"), 
                      new Order("1", "AA", "Completed"),
                      new Order("1", "AA", "Completed")
                      new Order("11", "AA", "Not Completed"), 
                      new Order("12", "AB", "Completed"), 
                      new Order("1", "DD", "Completed"),
                      new Order("1", "DD", "Completed"));

Function<Order, String> mapKey = order -> order.id + order.name + "COMPLETED";

// import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
var distinctOrders = t.stream().filter(p -> p.status == "Completed")
                               .collect(groupingBy(mapKey, toSet()));

// your distinct orders
distinctOrders.values().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to collect duplicates only for elements which have `status == COMPLETED` you could use a map with an appropriate key.

Ideally you'd provide your own key class which takes id, name and status and whose `equals()` deals status differently based on its value, e.g. like this:

```
boolean equals(Object other) {
  //check class, id and name first

  //in case of this key any status other than COMPLETE is unqiue and thus orders are not equal
  if( status != COMPLETE ) {
    return false;
  }

  //Key is the key class used for your map
  Key otherOrder = (Key)other;

  //if we reach this, this.status must be COMPLETE so just check other.status 
  return otherOrder.status == COMPLETE;
}
```

`hashCode()` should be implemented accordingly although it wouldn't matter if you just use `status.hashCode()` to build the key hash code. This would lead to collisions of incomplete orders with the same id and value but that could happen anyway and `equals()` would still make the keys distinct.

Then just put everything into a map:

```
Map<Key, Order> map = order.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                         o -> new Key(o), //map order to a new key
                                         o -> o,  //use the order as the value
                                         (l, r) -> l, //merge function to handle duplicates: keep the order already in the map 
                                         LinkedHashMap::new)); //use a LinkedHashMap to keep original order
```

If you don't want to use a custom key class you could use a list instead (like you're doing it already). Just map the status, e.g. like this lambda for the key mapper:

```
o -> List.of(o.id, o.name, o.status == COMPLETED ? o.status : new Object())
```

How does this work? `List.of(...)` returns an immutable list of type `ListN` whose `equals()` method calls `equals()` on elements at corresponding indices. If `id` and `name` are equal the "status" element will be checked. If you "map" any `COMPLETED` status to just that and any other status to `new Object()` you will effectively have equal keys for orders with the same id, name and status COMPLETED and unique keys for those with any other status (because `Object.equals()` uses instance identity only).