# Filter a java stream for distinct objects distinguishable according to an attribute without using collections

Tags: java, java-stream, distinct-values

i have a stream of objects (Measurements) including a private sensorID attribute. I want to filter this stream so i have only Measurements with different sensorIDs. To my understanding the "distinct" method would do that for the objects but not for a specific attribute of the objects. This code does the job by using Collections:

```
    public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
        Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
    }
```

and can be used like this

```
stream.filter(distinctByKey((Measurement p) -> p.getSensorId()))
```

for the Measurement class

```
public class Measurement {
    private final int sensorId;
    //more stuff
    
    public Measurement(int sensorId) {
        this.sensorId = sensorId;
        //more stuff
    }

    public int getSensorId() {
        return sensorId;
    }
}
```

What i am looking for is a way to do the same thing without using collections or atleast with immutable datatypes. Any idears?

Comment: why not override the `equals` method on `Measurements` ? and use `stream.distinct()` ?

Comment: Actuelly i tried this and it didnt work for me. Maybe i made a mistake?

Comment: you might have missed some thing, but you can take it as reference https://www.journaldev.com/31860/java-stream-distinct-function

Comment: @Deadpool Yes that helped - its actuelly the correct solution i just needed to also override the hashcode methode for it to work. Thanks

Comment: @DanielWagner the source code for `distinct` also has a very similar implementation using `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, as suggested by @Deadpool in his comment, was simple.
Just override the equals Methode of the Object.

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Measurement other = (Measurement) obj;
        return Objects.equals(sensorID, other.sensorID);
    }
```

but you also have to override the hashCode Methode like this

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(sensorID);
    }
```

Thats why it didnt work in the beginning.

Comment: I don’t think that implementing equality based on one property when the object has lots of others is a good idea. You are adapting the class’ overall design to suit a very specific single task. Be prepared for “weird behavior” in other scenarios when you don’t want all objects with the same sensor ID to be the same.

Comment: I do agree with @Holger comment here.

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative could be the usage of a collection to map, like the following example:

```java
Collection<Measurement> measurementsById = stream.
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Measurement::getSensorId, Function.identity(),
                (measurement1, measurement2) -> measurement1))
        .values()
```

In doing so, you are collecting the stream elements into a map keyed by `sensorId`. Since a map can have only one value for a key, you are simply selecting the first stream object for each key.

Then, given the result map, by calling `values()` method you get the list of distinct measurements you grouped by `sensorId`.

Comment: This is a solution with Collections. I am looking for solutions without Collections.

Comment: @DanielWagner what do you think how `distinct()` is implemented?