# Stream distinct by property but exclude by another property

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, distinct-values

### Setup and question

I have a stream over a simple Java data class like:

```java
class Candidate{
    private Long id;
    private String fullName;
    private String job;
    private String adress;
}
```

I would like to filter my stream by two properties:

- remove all duplicates by `job`
- but keep everyone with `adress` `"Italy"` regardless of `job`

---

### Example

Consider an example data set like

| ID | fullName | JOB | adress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter Bright | IT Engineer | Italy |
| 2 | Patrick Manon | Electronics engineer | Spain |
| 3 | Bob Jina | IT Engineer | Suisse |
| 4 | Alexander Layo | Security Engineer | UK |

or in Java:

```java
Candidate c1 = new Candidate(1,"Peter Bright","IT Engineer","Italy");
Candidate c2 = new Candidate(2,"Patrick Manon","Electronics engineer","Spain");
Candidate c3 = new Candidate(3,"Bob Jina","IT Engineer","Suisse");
Candidate c4 = new Candidate(4,"Alexander Layo","Security Engineer","UK");

Stream<Candidate> candidates = Stream.of(c1, c2, c3, c4);
```

I would like to filter the stream in a way that the outcome is:

| ID | fullName | JOB | ADSRESS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter Bright | IT Engineer | Italy |
| 2 | Patrick Manon | Electronics engineer | Spain |
| 4 | Alexander Layo | Security Engineer | UK |

Note that `Bob Jina` got removed since `IT Engineer` was already there.

**In the case of there is duplicates candidates all from Italy we need to keep all of them**

Comment: Please provide a sample code so we can reproduce, like the constructor, and sample data and sample list so we can directly try it

Comment: So you have a `Stream<Candidate>` to begine with?

Comment: @azro , sure , i have updated the post with some data

Comment: @Zabuzard , yes I would like to have that in a `List<Candidate>`

Comment: What if two "duplicate" candidates are italian? Keep a random? Keep first in list or last in list or random? What if none of two "duplicate" candidates are italian? Keep one from UK or Spain or random ..?

Comment: @Eritrean very good question ! yes I need to keep both

Answer (score 2):

You could collect to a map of `Candidate`s, using `job` as the key and keeping Italian candidates whenever there is a collision:

```
Collection<Candidate> result = candidates.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Candidate::getJob,
        Function.identity(),
        (c1, c2) -> "italy".equalsIgnoreCase(c1.getAddress()) ? c1 : c2,
        LinkedHashMap::new))
    .values();
```

This uses the overload of [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) that accepts four arguments.

I'm collecting to a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve *insertion-order*.

This solution returns candidates in a `Collection`, if you need a `List`, create it from the collection:

```
List<Candidate> list = new ArrayList<>(result);
```

Comment: That's awesome , but in the case of duplicate candidates and all are "italian" , I need to keep all of them!

Comment: @SafeMediaWeb That changes your original question and slightly complicates the problem... Do you mean that you want to keep all Italian candidates with the same job? Please clarify

Comment: @SafeMediaWeb Also, what if two candidates with the same job are from two different countries, other than Italy?

Comment: I am sorry i just realized that when testing

Comment: Yes if candidates have the same job and same location , i need to keep them all

Comment: To answer your question "what if two candidates with the same job are from two different countries, other than Italy?" , Italy should appear in this case , don't worry about that

Comment: hello @fps, sorry but I am getting a nullpointer exception when calling your method code  inside a test function ! do you have any idea why ?

Comment: @SafeMediaWeb Maybe some candidate instance is null, or its job

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, all jobs, regardless of job type and country will be kept unless Italy is involved. In that case, for any given job, only Italy's will be retained.

You can do it like so.  I chose two stages.

- first build a map keyed by jobs.
- then filter those jobs favoring Italy.

Create the map

```
Map<String, List<Candidate>> jobs = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Candidate::job));
```

Now, check all the lists.

- if the list for any job does not contain Italy, use that list in its entirety.
- otherwise, use the list excluding all but Italy.

```
List<Candidate> favorItaly = jobs.values()
     .stream()
     .map(lst -> {
              List<Candidate> italy = lst
                   .stream()
                   .filter(c -> c.getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("Italy"))
                   .toList();
              // if italy size is 0, use other, else use italy  
              return italy.size() == 0 ? lst : italy;
      })
     .flatMap(List::stream)
     .toList();
```

The two stages could have been combined but there is no performance improvement in doing so and this way avoids clutter.

Answer (score 1):

### Filter

You can achieve this quite easily by using [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) and a custom [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html) that is using a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) under the hood to memorize what candidates it already saw.

Also see this highly related answer [Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/2411243).

**Disclaimer:** This solution (like the linked answer) proposes a stateful predicate, which, in general, should be considered bad practice and error-prone for various reasons.

---

### Filter by distinct name

First of, lets create a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html) that only accepts a candidate if the **job name has not been seen yet**. Therefore, lets just steal the code from the post I linked above:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
}
```

We create our predicate by writing `distinctByKey(Candidate::getJob)`.

---

### Accept all Italians

The last part is to combine this predicate with a predicate that **just accepts anyone from Italy**, regardless of the job name:

```
Predicate<Candidate> acceptItalian = candidate -> candidate.getAddress().equals("Italy");
```

---

### Putting it together

Now lets combine both using [`Predicate#or`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#or(java.util.function.Predicate)) and use `filter` on the stream:

```
Stream<Candidate> candidates = ...
Stream<Candidate> filtered = candidates.filter(
    acceptItalian.or(distinctByKey(Candidate::getJob))
);
```

And now you have your filtered stream. Call `.toList()` on it to get a `List`, for example.

Note that its important that we put the two predicates together in that order. Otherwise the Italians would pollute the `Set` and lock out non-Itialians with the same job name. The functionality we rely on here is called **short-circuiting**, which `Predicate#or` does make use of (this is a documented feature you can rely on).

Comment: Using stateful predicates is discouraged and error-prone

Comment: @fps Generally I would agree on this, but  do you have an alternative? I dont. That said, I dont think there is anything bad with it in this particular situation. Keep the predicate short lived and tied to this stream iteration only (dont put it into a variable, dont expose it) and it is safe.

Comment: Uploaded an answer

Comment: @fps Thats a good alternative, I like it. I added a disclaimer to my answer so that our answers can co-exist in piece, haha.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Yes, your solution is correct, though a little more complex. It doesn't follow the java docs recommendation of using *stateless* predicates, either. But sometimes it's OK to break the rules :)

Comment: The problem of stateful predicates is demonstrated by the dependency on the order. It must be `distinctByKey(Candidate::getJob).or(acceptItalian)`, to be sure that the jobs of Italians still get recorded, even if they are accepted anyway, to prevent other non-Italian candidates with the same job. But even then, there’s still the problem that it makes a difference whether the non-Italian candidate have been seen first.