# Java 8 getting distinct elements from ArrayList Error

Tags: java-8

I am following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852) on getting distinct elements from ArrayList.

My code:

```
List<HpbAlertKeeperDTO> distinctAlertKeeperDTOs = alertKeeperDeviceDTO.getBizHpbAlertKeeperDTO().stream()
.filter(distinctByKey(HpbAlertKeeperDTO::getKeeperId)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and my distinctByKey is:

```
    protected static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
        Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
    }
```

But the error from the IDE is: it is highlighting the parameter of distinctByKey in the first code snippet.

> Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

My understanding of this error message is: getKeeperId() is not a static method. But in my HpbAlertKeeperDTO is just a normal POJO, with getter and setter methods of a variable.

How do I get around this error? Please feel free to ask me to provide more details.

Thanks and please help.

Comment: It's better if you can add your code as well

Comment: Use this its same solution. `Set<Integer> set =ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

alertKeeperDeviceDTO.getBizHpbAlertKeeperDTO()
.stream()
.filter(a -> set.add(a.getKeeperId())).collect(Collectors.toList()); `