# Filter stream distinct

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a stream over a simple Java data class like:

```java
class Developer{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer codePost;
    private Integer codeLevel;
}
```

I would like to apply this filter to my stream :

- if 2 dev has the same codePost with different codeExperience keep the dev with codeLevel = 5
- keep all devs if Developers has the same codePost with the same codeLevel

### Example

| ID | name | codePost | codeExperience |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alan stonly | 30 | 4 |
| 2 | Peter Zola | 20 | 4 |
| 3 | Camilia Frim | 30 | 5 |
| 4 | Antonio Alcant | 40 | 4 |

or in java

```java
Developer dev1 = new Developer (1,"Alan stonly",30,4);
Developer dev2 = new Developer (2,"Peter Zola",20,4);
Developer dev3 = new Developer (3,"Camilia Frim ",30,5);
Developer dev4 = new Developer (4,"Antonio Alcant",40,4);

Stream<Developer> Developers = Stream.of(dev1, dev2, dev3 , dev4);
```

Comment: Streams are not very well-suited to problems that need to take the state of previous entries into account. You could collect your entries with the 3 args version of [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)), with `codePost` as key and 'merging' the values to keep the one you want.

Comment: `developers.collect(Collectors.toMap(Developer::getCodePost, Function.identity(),BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Developer::getCodeLevel)))).values();`

Comment: @Hulk yes that seems good, but how I could filter by the codeExperience in my case?

Comment: Well, forget it - the approach shown in [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/2513200) (stateful `Predicate` in `Stream.filter()`) is not applicatble to your case, because you cannot take back what you already emitted after the fact. I've retracted my duplicate-close vote. I'd just use a Map - either somthing along the lines of [the comment by Hadi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69462527/filter-stream-distinct?noredirect=1#comment122776344_69462527) or simply with a loop instead of a Stream.

Comment: _keep all devs if Developers has the same codePost with the same codeLevel_ if there are 4 devs, two have codeLevel = 2, and the other two have codeLevel = 3, which devs should be kept: the ones with the lowest codeLevel, those with the max codeLevel, all of them, or none of them?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `Collectors.toMap` should be used here with the merge function (and optionally a map supplier, e.g. `LinkedHashMap::new` to keep insertion order):

```java
Stream.of(dev1, dev2, dev3, dev4)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Developer::getCodePost,
        dev -> dev,
        (d1, d2) -> Stream.of(d1, d2)
                          .filter(d -> d.getCodeLevel() == 5)
                          .findFirst()
                          .orElse(d1),
        LinkedHashMap::new // keep insertion order
    ))
    .values()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The merge function may be implemented with ternary operator too:

```java
(d1, d2) -> d1.getCodeLevel() == 5 ? d1 : d2.codeLevel() == 5 ? d2 : d1
```

Output:

```
Developer(id=3, name=Camilia Frim , codePost=30, codeLevel=5)
Developer(id=2, name=Peter Zola, codePost=20, codeLevel=4)
Developer(id=4, name=Antonio Alcant, codePost=40, codeLevel=4)
```

---

If the output needs to be sorted in another order, `values()` should be sorted as `values().stream().sorted(DeveloperComparator)` with a custom developer comparator, e.g. `Comparator.comparingLong(Developer::getId)` or `Comparator.comparing(Developer::getName)` etc.

---

**Update**

As the devs sharing the same `codeLevel` should NOT be filtered out, the following (a bit clumsy) solution is possible on the basis of `Collectors.collectingAndThen` and `Collectors.groupingBy`:

1. input list is grouped into a map of `codePost` to the list of developers
2. then the `List<Developer>` values in the map are filtered to keep the devs with max `codeLevel`

```java
// added two more devs
Developer dev5 = new Developer (5L,"Donkey Hot",40,3);
Developer dev6 = new Developer (6L,"Miguel Servantes",40,4);

Stream.of(dev1, dev2, dev3, dev4, dev5, dev6)
      .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(
              Developer::getCodePost
      ), map -> {
          map.values()
             .stream()
             .filter(devs -> devs.size() > 1)
             .forEach(devs -> {
                 int maxLevel = devs.stream()
                     .mapToInt(Developer::getCodeLevel)
                     .max().orElse(5);
                 devs.removeIf(x -> x.getCodeLevel() != maxLevel);
             });
          return map;
      }))
      .values()
      .stream()
      .flatMap(List::stream)
      .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(Developer::getId))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
Developer(id=2, name=Peter Zola, codePost=20, codeLevel=4)
Developer(id=3, name=Camilia Frim , codePost=30, codeLevel=5)
Developer(id=4, name=Antonio Alcant, codePost=40, codeLevel=4)
Developer(id=6, name=Miguel Servantes, codePost=40, codeLevel=4)
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply but I need to keep all devloper if Developers has the same codePost with the same codeLevel

Comment: Why did not you post this requirement in the original post?  Are there other cases like two or more devs have the came codePost but different codeLevel and nobody has codeLevel == 5?

Comment: i thought this condition should not be added to the filter , but after testing I have realized it should be . sorry I added that to original post .