# Is there a simpler way to remove "duplicate" objects from an array (objects with the same property)?

Tags: java, arraylist

If, given an array of objects, such as:

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.aslist(
new Person("Victoria", 25, "Firefighter"),
new Person("Grace", 27, "Footballer"),
new Person("Samantha", 25, "Stock Broker"),
new Person("Victoria", 23, "Poker Player"),
new Person("Jane", 27, "Footballer"),
new Person("Grace", 25, "Security Guard"));
```

How can one remove any objects that don't have a unique attributes, whilst leaving only one. This could be as simple as duplicate names, which would leave:

```
Person("Victoria", 25, "Firefighter"),
Person("Grace", 27, "Footballer"),
Person("Samantha", 25, "Stock Broker"),
Person("Jane", 27, "Footballer")
```

Or more complex, such as jobs that start with the same letter, and the same age:

```
Person("Victoria", 25, "Firefighter"),
Person("Grace", 27, "Footballer"),
Person("Samantha", 25, "Stock Broker"),
Person("Victoria", 23, "Poker Player"),
```

So far, the best I've come up with is:

```
    int len = people.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
            if (function(people.get(i), people.get(j))) {
                people.remove(j);
                j--;
                len--;
            }
    }
```

With "function" checking if the entries are considered "duplicates"

I was wondering if there's a library that does just this, or if you could somehow put this in a lambda expression

Comment: implement equals on Person object, and use stream distinct() ---< Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to Object.equals(Object)) of this stream.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-remove-duplicates-from-list

Comment: Would you like to provide a fixed or (maybe) varying function for checking dupliated?

Comment: Your "duplicates" are not necessarily identical to each other.  Does it matter, then, which object among each group of duplicates is retained?  Also, is it an essential feature that object equivalence is tested via a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say "remove duplicates", the first thing which comes into my mind, is using a `Set`. However, `Set` considers an object as "duplicate" if the set already contains an object which is "equal" to that object, by means of the `equals` method. Implementing `Person::equals` to check for a job's first letter is not a good fit.

You want to have another sort of 'equals method' for this use case alone. But we have to use something else, as sacrificing `equals` for this use case alone should not be done.

The `Stream` interface contains a `distinct()` method to check for duplicates, but `distinct` doesn't take a parameter where you can pass in a sort of `Comparator` or `Predicate` to define *when* a `Person` is considered "distinct" from another `Person`.

Fortunately, [this excellent StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/507738) provides exactly what you need:

```java
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
}
```

Now the next thing you must do, is create a record to collect the appropriate object properties:

```java
record PersonAgeAndJobFilter(int age, char jobFirstLetter) {

    public static PersonAgeAndJobFilter ofPerson(Person p) {
        return new PersonAgeAndJobFilter(p.getAge(), p.getJob().charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Then stream over the `people`, using your filter:

```java
people.stream()
    .filter(distinctByKey(PersonAgeAndJobFilter::ofPerson))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

---

Alternatively, it can also be achieved with a combination of `groupingBy`:

```java
Collection<Person> persons = people.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(PersonAgeAndJobFilter::ofPerson, collectingAndThen(reducing((a, b) -> a), Optional::get)))
    .values();
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
ArrayList<Person> new_people = people.stream()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I hope It will work for you.

Comment: Streams are a nice idea. But make sure, that your equals() and hashCode() methods are properly overwritten, so that distinct() is working properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map to pick distinct values by the attribute. This is a method that can be called with a list of objects and a key mapper that picks the attribute that determines uniqueness:

```
private static <T> List<T> uniqueBy(List<T> objects, 
         Function<T, Object> keyExtractor) {
    return new ArrayList<>(objects.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(keyExtractor, 
                                      Function.identity(), 
                                      (a, b) -> a, 
                                      LinkedHashMap::new)).values());
}
```

That uses `LinkedHashMap` to preserve order from the source list. The method can be used in this way:

```
List<Person> uniqueByName = uniqueBy(people, Person::getName); //by name
List<Person> uniqueByAge = uniqueBy(people, Person::getAge); //by age
//etc.
```