# Java stream api: filtration inner collections

Tags: java, java-stream

I have `List<List<String>>`. How can I filter the list so that only unique lists remain in it using java streams api?

For example: from `originalList` to `resultList`:

```
List<List<String>> originalList = List.of(
    List.of("abc", "cba"),
    List.of("cba", "abc"),
    List.of("123", "321")
);

List<List<String>> resultList = List.of(
    List.of("abc", "cba"),
    List.of("123", "321")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As [List.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is does ensure equal content,[stream.distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()) would be enough if der different order of elements is considered different, but your example shows that you want to ignore order.

I would recommend to use a non-stream approach in this case, as streams work best when elements can be processed independently.

You need a stateful intermediate filter here, as it needs to remember the elements already checked. One approch would be adding elements to a [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) with custom comparator, and allow only elements for which the add-method returns true.

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property) shows how to implent such a filter.

---

Alternatively, convert the inner lists to `LinkedHashSets` for the purpose of filtering - this is the simplest approach in terms of code size:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            
    List<List<String>> originalList = List.of(
            List.of("abc", "cba"),
            List.of("cba", "abc"),
            List.of("123", "321")
        );
                
        List<List<String>> result2 = originalList.stream()
                .map(LinkedHashSet::new) // Note: does not support null values
                .distinct()
                .map(List::copyOf) // Note: does not support null values
                .toList();
        
        result2.forEach(System.out::println);           
}
```

Prints:

```
[abc, cba]
[123, 321]
```

Answer (score 0):

> so that only **unique lists** remain

Judging by your example, the following lists `["abc", "cba"]` and `["cba", "abc"]` are considered to be duplicates (which obviously isn't aligned with how equality is defined by the `List` interface).

I infer your definition of equality as: *two lists are equal if every element from the first list appear the same number of times in the second list, regardless of the order*.

We can eliminate duplicates in a *linear time* **O(n)** by making use of standard *hash-based* mechanisms like method `Stream.distinct()`.

For that, we need to create a wrapper-class which would implement `equals/hashCode` contract as described above.

The following class exposes a `static` method `of()` which internally generates a *map of frequencies* for every element in the given list (which would is needed for equality checks) and *hash code of the map of frequencies* (which would be reused instead of being recalculated) and return an instance of wrapper class.

```
class ListWrapper<T> {
    private List<T> list;
    private Map<T, Integer> frequencies;
    private final int hash; // hash code of the Map of frequencies generated from the List would be computed only once and reused
    
    private ListWrapper(List<T> list, Map<T, Integer> frequencies, int hash) { // should not be invoked from outside
        this.list = list;
        this.frequencies = frequencies;
        this.hash = hash;
    }
    
    public static <T> ListWrapper<T> of(List<T> list) {
        Map<T, Integer> freq = getFrequencies(list);
        
        return new ListWrapper<>(list, freq, freq.hashCode());
    }
    
    public static <T> Map<T, Integer> getFrequencies(List<T> list) {
        
        return list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(),
                item -> 1,
                Integer::sum
            ));
    }
    
    public List<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        
        if (o instanceof ListWrapper<?> other) {
            return Objects.equals(this.frequencies, other.frequencies);
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hash;
    }
}
```

And that's how we can use it.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<List<String>> originalList = List.of(
        List.of("abc", "cba"),
        List.of("cba", "abc"),
        List.of("123", "321")
    );
    
    List<List<String>> resultList = originalList.stream()
        .map(ListWrapper::of)      // wrapping a list
        .distinct()                // eliminating duplicates
        .map(ListWrapper::getList) // unwrapping a list
        .toList();                 // or .collect(Collectors.toList()) for Java 15 and earlier

    resultList.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*Output:*

```
[abc, cba]
[123, 321]
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tr5)