# Can I make my code cleaner using Streams in Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of Merchant objects with (Merchant Code, purchase ref, ...etc).
It would look something like:

```
1, purchase abc, description
1, purchase cde, descr 2
2, purachase fed, desc 4
3, purchase fij, desc  55
```

My goal is to count the number of unique Merchant Codes, so from the list above, I would receive 3.

I got this Java code:

```
int numberOfUniqueMerchanCodes = myListOfMerchantRecords.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t->t.getMerchantCode())).size();
```

Can I do it shorter as I don't really need to collect the items, I just need to count the number of distinct MerchantCodes?

Comment: Could you share your Merchant record code?

Comment: Maybe something like `.map(c - c.getMC()).distinct().count()`. Or read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)

Comment: Try @MarcoBalo's suggestion; this appears to be more specific.

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Devise the briefest possible example to show your issue.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can make your code like this

```
long numberOfUniqueMerchantCodes = myListOfMerchantRecords.stream()
            .map(MerchantRecord::getMerchantCode)
            .distinct()
            .count();
```