# Filter Out Duplicates from a Stream By Property Value

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to filter out duplicates from a `Stream` by object id... and this is my attempt:

```
private Function<Stream<Person>, Stream<Person>> filterDuplicates() {
    return stream -> stream
        .collect(
            collectingAndThen(
                toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(comparingLong(Person::getId))),
                ArrayList::new))
        .stream();
}
```

As I still need a `Stream`, is it possible to filter `Stream` to `Stream` and avoid the intermediate `ArrayList`?

Comment: If you update `Person#equals` to account for `#getId`, and assuming a sequential (non-parallel) stream, _and_ if you are okay with side effects, you can keep a `HashSet<?> set`, and then `return stream.filter(set::add);`. Since `Set#add` only returns `true` for uniquely added elements, the stream will also only process unique elements. Otherwise, `return stream.filter(p -> set.add(p.getId());`

Comment: Just realized there's also [Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your request. Why don't you stream from the TreeSet without collecting to ArrayList?

```
private static Function<Stream<Person>, Stream<Person>> filterDuplicates() {
    return stream -> stream
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingLong(Person::getId))))
        .stream();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Wrappers with `distinct`

You could work around that by creating a wrapper object, use [`Stream#distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()) to filter by that attribute and then converting back.

```java
record DistinctWrapper<T>(T element, Object filter){

    public DistinctWrapper{
        Objects.requireNonNull(element);
        Objects.requireNonNull(filter);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return filter.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        if(other instanceof DistinctWrapper<?> o){
            return filter.equals(o.filter());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can then use this wrapper on `distinct` and it should only check the `filter` object:

```java
private Function<Stream<Person>, Stream<Person>> filterDuplicates() {
    return stream -> stream
        .map(person -> new DistinctWrapper(person, person.getId()))//convert to wrapper
        .distinct()//get distinct elements, only compares filter
        .map(DistinctWrapper::element);//convert back to object
}
```

### Collecting

Of course, you can also just add it to a `Set` and get a `Stream` again.

If you want to preserve the order, you can use `LinkedHashSet`.

```java
private Function<Stream<Person>, Stream<Person>> filterDuplicates() {
    return stream -> stream
        .collect(Collectors::toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))
        .stream();
}
```

### Gatherers in the future

Furthermore, JDK 22 will come with a preview feature called [Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) which allow to introduce custom intermediate operations.

```java
public static <B> Gatherer<T,?,T> distinctBy(Function<T,B> by){
    Gatherer<T,Set<B>,T> gatherer = Gatherer.ofSequential(
        HashSet::new,
        (previous, element, downstream) -> {
            B filter = by.apply(element);
            if(!previous.contains(filter)){
                previous.add(filter);
                return downstream.push(element);
            }
            return true;//accept more elements
        }
    );

    return gatherer;
}
```

and you could then use it like this:

```java
yourStream
    .gather(distinctBy(Person::getId))
    //further processing
```

Answer (score 2):

As I don't fully understand your use case I am just returning a stream and not a Function since the Function would be limited to a particular type or an already exhausted stream.

Here is a solution that lets you selectively filter any stream based on a particular field or the object itself and returns the stream directly.

First, create a record for demonstration and construct a source stream.

```
record Person(Integer getId, int getAge) {
}
Builder<Person> builder = Stream.builder();
for (int i : new int[]{1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,6,2,1,2,3,4,5,6}) {
    builder.add(new Person(i, ((i+3)/2)*15));
}
Stream<Person> originalStream = builder.build();
```

**Datails of the method**

- Passing an source `Stream<T>` and a `Function<T,R>` to the `filterDuplicates` method.  The `Function` is used to provide a filter target `T` for field type `R`.
- Use a `Set<R>` to detect and hold duplicates for the field type.
- Using `multiMap` to process stream elements and check the set.  If present, the object has already been detected so ignore, otherwise, pass it on to the stream.

**Operation**

To invoke `filterDuplicates` and apply the returned stream do something like the following:

```
Stream<Person> newStream = filterDuplicates(originalStream, Person::getId)
List<Person> list = newStream.toList();
```

**Full working demo**

```
public class NewStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Builder<Person> builder = Stream.builder();
        for (int i : new int[]{1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,6,2,1,2,3,4,5,6}) {
            builder.add(new Person(i, ((i+3)/2)*15));
        }
        Stream<Person> originalStream = builder.build();

        Stream<Person> newStream = filterDuplicates(originalStream,
                Person::getId);

        List<Person> list = newStream.toList();
        list.forEach(System.out::println);    
    }

    private static <T, R> Stream<T> filterDuplicates(Stream<T> stream,
            Function<T, R> fnc) {
        Set<R> dups = new HashSet<>();
        return  stream.mapMulti((ob, consumer) -> {
            if (dups.add(fnc.apply(ob))) {
                consumer.accept(ob);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

prints

```
Person[getId=1, getAge=30]
Person[getId=2, getAge=30]
Person[getId=3, getAge=45]
Person[getId=4, getAge=45]
Person[getId=5, getAge=60]
Person[getId=6, getAge=60]
```

To filter on the complete object, use `Function.identity()` or `ob->ob` as the filter target.

**Note:**  The above requires that both `equals` and `hashCode` be overridden in accordance with the `JavaDoc` for class `Object`.