# Using .filter and Set combination instead of .distinct to find unique items in java stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am contemplating using this setup instead of distinct to find unique items.

```
Set<String> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
List<String> names = people.stream()
                           .map(Person::getName)
                           .filter(seen::add)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Does it achieve better parallellization and performance this way by converting distinct to a stateless operation?

Comment: No.  You can't execute this stream operation in parallel as you have written it.  Due to the modification of the set, the order matters.  If all elements were checked in parallel, none of them would exist in the set yet and your filter would not remove anything.  It is good practice to avoid mutations when performing maps and filters to prevent these kind of errors.

Comment: @Razumov The set is backed by `ConcurrentHashMap` so adding `.parallel()` above doesn't change what entries are identified. Obviously the ordering of the list returned would change if run in parallel, and `seen` should only be used for once.

Comment: The accepted answer for [distinct by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property/27872852#27872852) shows a nicer way to setup a filter by distinct key value, and such that the set cannot accidentally be re-used.

Comment: There’s a fundamental misconception shown when you say “by converting distinct to a stateless operation”. It’s not even clear what you think what a stateless operation is, when you think that what you did here was a stateless operation. Your code is a textbook example of a stateful operation.