Java Stream Filter Predicate allowing wrong itens
fellows.
To be short: I need to filter a List to have just itens who have differences on some fields.
This is because I need to show to the Auditor the differences on the Object throught the time.
I have this pseudo class, where on my app represents a Hibernate Envers model:
class SystemAudit {
    Int id;
    String descriptionFieldA;
    String descriptionFieldB;
    String descriptionFieldC;
    
    // Constructor, gets and sets
}

After load it from database, I have something like this:
List<SystemAudit> systemAuditList = new ArrayList<>();
systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(0, "A0", "B0", "C0"));
systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(1, "A0", "B1", "C0"));
systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(2, "A0", "B1", "C0"));
systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(3, "A1", "B1", "C0"));
systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(4, "A1", "B2", "C0"));
systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(5, "A1", "B2", "C0"));
systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(6, "A2", "B2", "C0"));
systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(7, "A2", "B3", "C1"));
systemAuditList.add(new SystemAudit(8, "A2", "B3", "C1"));

When I ask to remove all itens who have same value at some property, it works whell, take a look:
List<SystemAudit> systemAuditListFiltered = systemAuditList.stream()
        .filter(StreamUtil.filtrarPorArgumento(SystemAudit::getDescriptionFieldA))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

public class Streamutil {
    public static <T> Predicate<T> filtrarPorArgumento(Function<? super T, ?> argumento) {
        Set<Object> argsEncontrados = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        return t -> argsEncontrados.add(argumento.apply(t));
    }
}

(This above was inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/13635010)
The result is correctly like this:
systemAuditListFiltered content:
(0, "A0", "B0", "C0")
(3, "A1", "B1", "C0")
(6, "A2", "B2", "C0")

But, if I chain the Predicate, it looks like my filtrarPorArgumento let invalid itens, look:
systemAuditListFiltered = systemAuditList.stream()
        .filter(StreamUtil.filtrarPorArgumento(SystemAudit::getDescriptionFieldA)
                .or(StreamUtil.filtrarPorArgumento(SystemAudit::getDescriptionFieldB))
                .or(StreamUtil.filtrarPorArgumento(SystemAudit::getDescriptionFieldC)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

The systemAuditListFiltered content:
(0, "A0", "B0", "C0")
(1, "A0", "B1", "C0")
(2, "A0", "B1", "C0") // This is a wrong item
(3, "A1", "B1", "C0")
(4, "A1", "B2", "C0")
(6, "A2", "B2", "C0")
(7, "A2", "B3", "C1")
(8, "A2", "B3", "C1") // This is a wrong item

Just remember: I'm NOT comparing the SystemAudit.id
Where am I wrong?
With the above systemAuditList loaded, I expect the systemAuditListFiltered content to be like:
(0, "A0", "B0", "C0")
(1, "A0", "B1", "C0")
(3, "A1", "B1", "C0")
(4, "A1", "B2", "C0")
(6, "A2", "B2", "C0")
(7, "A2", "B3", "C1")
(8, "A2", "B3", "C1")

Edit:
Reproducible code:
https://onecompiler.com/java/42zfp99xj

ok ... according to the filter you've set. why are those values invalid? It might be best if you made a clear description of what you expact as a result and an actual (complete yet minimal) reproducible example

I thought this above was reproducible, i'll try some better. Wait a moment please. And about what I'm expecting, the itens who have same properties need to be out of systemAuditListFiltered. The itens 2 and 8 are invalid because they are exactly same as te previous: item 2 = 1 and 8 = 7.

The logic is correct. You need to filter distinct on A+B+C..

just .filter(StreamUtil.filtrarPorArgumento(a -> List.of( a.getDescriptionFieldA(), a.getDescriptionFieldB(), a.getDescriptionFieldC())))

With the distinctByKey method at the duplicate link, you can systemAuditList.stream().filter( distinctByKey( a -> a.getDescriptionFieldA() + a.getDescriptionFieldB() + a.getDescriptionFieldC() )).toList();  which may or may not be a bit clearer.

I cloud reach my target using this answer as reference. On my case, the result was: systemAuditList.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(SystemAudit::getDescriptionFieldA, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())).thenComparing(SystemAudit::getDescriptionFieldB, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())).thenComparing(SystemAudit::getDescriptionFieldC, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))))), ArrayList::new));
Thank you all.

@markspace I don’t understand why people always come up with string concatenation for this purpose. It’s horribly expensive and relies on the assumption that the strings will always be such that there’s no ambiguity like "A" + "BC" vs "AB" + "C". While the previously shown alternative, List.of(…) produces keys cheaply (no copying of strings) and without ambiguity.

@Holger sorry for the misunderstanding. I'll delete my previous comment. Thanks for your suggestion. I didn't try it because another one worked.
